# Как изучить алгоритмы и структуры данных?

Tags: алгоритм, структуры, структуры-данных

Всем привет! Изучая программирование я наткнулся на один очень интересный предмет - алгоритмы и структуры данных. И сразу же возник вопрос: как правильно следует их изучать? То есть у меня есть представление по каждой из основных структур данных, но тем не менее хотелось бы больше узнать об области применения каждой из них и начать использовать нужную структуру в нужном месте.

Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать ресурс или дать направление куда двигаться? Просто при поиске натыкаюсь либо на описание структур данных, либо на их реализацию

Кстати о реализации, следует ли самому попробовать их написать и ознакомиться с внутренностями каждой структуры данных? Просто не вижу в этом особой необходимости и пользы...

Comment: Не уверен, что это дубль, но, по-моему, вам сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/576507/195342

Comment: Вот [тут](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56427267#56427267) хоть я и писал про собеседования, но есть материал про подготовку к алгоритмам.