# Посоветуйте книги по алгоритмам

Tags: алгоритм, книги

Всем привет, я новичок в программировании и сейчас изучаю алгоритмы. Прочитал простенькую книгу "Грокаем алгоритмы" Адитья Бхаргава, меня очень затянуло. Оказывается алгоритмы очень интересная вещь. В процессе даже в блокноте их порисовал) Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, какие несложные книги по алгоритмам можно еще прочесть, сухую документацию я, скорее всего, не вывезу и ее банально скучно читать. Если нескучных в вашем арсенале нет, посоветуйте хотя бы очень полезную.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/576508/195342

Comment: [вот эта](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/) самая клевая из всех, что я читал, она есть на русском + есть курс на курсере по ней из 2 частей. А вообще как то делал подборку [здесь](https://github.com/Entering-IT/documentation/blob/main/interview/algorithms_basics.md).