# Подготовка к codility

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Добрый день, прошу помочь составить список литературы для подготовке к тесту https://codility.com/. Сам я пишу на Objective C, пытался устроиться на работу и провалил тест. Начал читать Книги по дискретной математике, но вот какую книгу выбрать по алгоритмам, так и не могу определиться, очень надеюсь на ваши советы.

Comment: А видели вот это - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474415 ?

Comment: Да спасибо, если возможно, то мне нужна помощь в более сжатом варианте.

Comment: Вообще-то вопросы типа "Какое Х выбрать" или "Какая Y лучше" здесь не приветствуются, поскольку 1) на них не может существовать верных или неверных ответов (всё субъективно); 2) Такого рода вопросы очень часто ведут к холиварам, которым здесь не место.

Comment: Спасибо, я вас понял.