# Web-программирование с нуля

Tags: веб-программирование

Посоветуйте с чего начать учить web-программирование, если уровень знаний у человека в этой области минимальный, чтобы в дальнейшем уметь делать более менее приемлемые сайты. Посоветуйте литературу, статьи и прочую полезную информацию для новичка в этой сфере.

Comment: как один из вариантов — https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn

Comment: Web-программирование - это слишком обще. вот совсем. то есть даже непонятно какой язык нужен вам.

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по фундаментальным знаниям и навыкам разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474415/191482) |  [Книги и другие материалы для обучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/191482)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы видимо не поняли сути вопроса. Вопрос заключается в том, чтобы понять с какого языка и стоит начинать и что в дальнейшем продолжать изучать.

Comment: @ЖеняРыбалко `с какого языка и стоит начинать` - с любого какой хотите) что нравится? о каком слышали? бэкенд? фронденд?

Comment: Так наверное так и надо было написать в вопросе. вы же книги спросили. А web-разработка слишком широкий вопрос, вот вам и дали широкий диапазон книг. В web-разработке используются: HTML, CSS (хотя это и не ЯП), JavaScript, PHP, C#, Java, Ruby, Python, Perl и еще десяток языков. Это только часто используемые, а так в принципе (как недавно обсуждалось в другом вопросе) для web-разработки может использоваться вообще любой язык

Comment: Предположу, что вы можете начать с html, css, Javascript и фреймворков для js, а с сервером определиться позже. Если вообще в него захотите. Может быть полностью отдадите себя фронтенду

Comment: @ЖеняРыбалко, скажите, пожалуйста, а почему вы думаете, что мы, ничего не зная о вас и ни разу в глаза вас не видев, можем что-то посоветовать вам?

Comment: @mymedia А вы ответе, неужели не возможно понять уровень знаний человека, который в заголовке указывает "с нуля" ?

Comment: @ЖеняРыбалко но это же явная неправда, вы как минимум неплохо знаете русский язык, чтобы на нём изъясняться. А существенная часть разработки это вытягивание из заказчика/начальника требований через общение. Так что на практике "с нуля" обычно понятие ну очень растяжимое.