# Подскажите книгу по алгоритмам (желательно по C/C++ или на псевдокоде)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, книги

Нужен именно по алгоритмам, предполагая что я знаю переменные, циклы, функции, классы, шаблоны и т.д. А если там будут еще и задания, я вас  расцелую(эх, мечты)

Comment: Алгоритмы Справочник Д.Хайнеман

Comment: Или вот: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по фундаментальным знаниям и навыкам разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474415/Книги-и-учебные-ресурсы-по-фундаментальным-знаниям-и-навыкам-разработчика)

Answer (score 0):

***Т. Кормен Алгоритмы, построение и анализ (третье издание)***

Хорошая книга по алгоритмам с упражнениями и примерами на псевдокоде.