# Материалы для начинающего программиста, и советы

Tags: алгоритм

В этом вопросе я имею виду любые материалы, не конкретного языка программирования, или сферы программирования.

**Пример.** Книги, видеоуроки, специальные сайты.

Так же, советы по всей сфере программирования, не только по программированию на определенном языке.

**Пример.** Отладка своих проектов; Использование среды программирования Visual studio.

Надеюсь вы меня поняли.

Я недавно зарегистрировался, и надеюсь то что я не нарушаю никаких законов "stack**overflow**".

Comment: [Клик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/книги?sort=votes&pageSize=15)

Comment: По алгоритмам - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576507/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B

Comment: [Книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474415/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги по теме "Алгоритмы"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576507/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d1%8b)