# Создание python компилятора

Tags: python

Недавно увлёкся созданием мобильных приложений так как учусь на програмиста. В Play Market есть огромное количество Python компиляторов под андроид. Я хотел бы написать свой компилятор. Слышал что код пайтон является открытым и каждый может изменять его и тд... Можете подсказать пожалуйста, где можно взять сам код компилятора и какую литературу для обучения мне желательно почитать. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по фундаментальным знаниям и навыкам разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474415/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2):

Прежде всего, Python - это интерпретируемый язык. Начать стоит с того, чтобы научиться отличать интерпретацию от компиляции. [Код эталонной реализации](https://github.com/python/cpython) можно найти на GitHub. А почитать можно "[SICP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC)" и "[книгу дракона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B:_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B,_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B)". Ещё "[The Garbage Collection Handbook](http://gchandbook.org/)" может пригодиться.