# Какой у вас алгоритм решения задач?

Tags: javascript

Часто на собеседованиях дают задачи такого типа или похожи:
Написать функцию, которая принимает целое число и выводит в консоль таблицу умножения этого числа от 1 до 99

```
    document.querySelector('#task-4').onclick = function () {

    let num = document.querySelector('#num-4').value;

    num = parseInt(num);

    if (!isNaN(num)) {

        for (let i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {

            console.log(`${i}*${num}=${i * num}`);

        }

    }

}
```

Какой у вас алгоритм решения таких задач по пунктам?
1.
2.
3.
4.
5. 
и т.д.

Comment: Есть такой раздел в программировании, как разработка и проектирование программного обеспечения. Может даже можно что-то найти в [фундаментальных трудах на ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474415/Книги-и-учебные-ресурсы-по-фундаментальным-знаниям-и-навыкам-разработчика). Очень простые задачи решаются на уровне рефлексов уже. Обычные задачи решаются сначала аналитически без кодирования, потом расписывается действия по шагам (возможно с наметками кода) и потом алгоритм переносится в код. Для сложных задач придумано куча всяких техник и шаблонов проектирования.

Comment: Решение конкретно этой задачи всплывает в голове моментально после прочтения задачи, и алгоритмам с пунктами тут просто неоткуда взяться