# Стоит ли читать Герберта Шилда C# 4.0 или как выбрать актуальную, фундаментальную, полезную литературу для новичков в программировании?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Я хочу стать backend/frontend разработчиком, но как говорится разделяй и властвуй, я выбрал Backend, и начал копать языки, остановился на C#/ASP.net, принялся ГУГЛИТЬ, узнал какие есть ресурсы, книги, курсы!

Я собирался занимать в такой последовательности!

1. Герберт Шилд C# 4.0
2. Параллельно Метанит
3. Троилсен C# 7.0 и канал в Ютубе Христа C# хвалят многие!
4. написать что то простое не просто тупо копи паст, а уже имея базовые знания после 2 книг, а затем взять Рихтен CLR C#

Все это я думаю пройти до лета, а затем в начале лета, я ухожу с работы и думаю 4-5 месяцев фул тайм практиковаться и закреплять полученные знания!

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по фундаментальным знаниям и навыкам разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474415/179763), [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/179763)

Answer (score 3):

Эти книги - руководство по языку и по фреймворку в целом.

Те главы, что покрывают десктопную разработку, можете пропустить.

Те главы, что покрывают веб разработку под 4.0 - устарели, Microsoft сменил веб фреймворк, на Asp.net Core. Часть опыта с Asp.net MVC, конечно, переносима на Core, но у вас опыта нет, лучше учить с нуля именно Core версию.

Любая книга по Asp.net Core 2+ будет полезнее, чем Шилдт или Троелсен по старому 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, на стеке C#/Asp.Net(Core) работают и ищут обычно фулл-стак разработчиков, так что скорее всего прийдется учить и всякие js фреймворки (angular/react/..) + html, css. Метанит хорош для новеньких, но на самом деле он объясняет иногда не всё что делает и на собеседованиях качественные работодатели эти ошибки отлавливают. Но, если юзать метанит параллельно читая книги, то всё ок. Из вышеперечисленного читал только Рихтера поэтому скажу только о нем. Новых людей может оттолкнуть начало со всей этой темой о CLR, сборках, метаданных и тд., но это на самом деле важно для понимания как всё работает. Но он, мне кажется лучше подойдет тем, кто уже что-то знает о программировании. Но тут только сам язык C#. Дальше надо найти материалы о фреймворке (лучше asp.net CORE, сейчас майкрософты в основном нацелены на него, новые проекты в основном пилят уже на нём). Но главное, это всё подтверждать практикой. Практика, практика и еще раз практика. Прочитал главу - написал что-то используя новый материал. Итак, язык изучили и перешли к фреймворку. Теперь желательно изучить паттерны в ООП (от GoF можно почитать) и почитать об архитектурных шаблонах (напр. MVC, который часто используется с asp.net), что-то об архитектуре приложений по желанию ("Чистая архитектура" от автора "Чистый код", который тоже можно почитать), принципах SOLID, методологиях разработки (agile, scrum и тд.). А вообще, многие компании делают курсы для дальнейшего набора на джунов, так что читаете основу ( например, только книгу о языке + практика), проходите отбор на курсы (ещё очень важно знать английский язык, хотя бы на B1, часто на собеседовании идет простой диалог), а на них уже будут учить всё остальное что я описал выше. Успехов вам в этом.

Comment: Спасибо! Прочитал ваш комент 4 раза! Я уже подумывал стоя на работе за станком что просто asp net это мало, нужен Angular

Answer (score 0):

Мое обучение было таким и считаю его самым адекватным. Для начала мне кажется все знаний что ты будешь черпать из книг что ты перечислил пройдут мимо и придется читать все заново через год-два. Просто бери и смотри курсы на ITVDN и выполняй домашние задания. Там есть видео ответы к ним что очень удобно, постепенно твой мозг привыкнет к реализации простых программ и тогда можно постепенно помещать в свою голову что такое CLR и CLI. На первом этапе это будет бессмысленно. Самое главное что там есть roadmap что порядку надо учить. Очень удобно и систематизировано. Просто суть моего совета такова. Начни просто кодить простые консольные приложухи с первых дней как на видео там и выполняй домашнии задания, даже если не все понятно - продолжай идти по курсу, потом допрет, оно реально так работает. И где-то через годик, может меньше начинай читать то как ты выбрал. Я б Рихтера на первое место поставил, Троилсена сейчас читаю, забиваю свои пробелы. Троилсена не могу советовать, покамись 6/7 по моей оценке. Как бы так. Это лично мой опыт, а решение принимать тебе.

Comment: А вы попали на работу? Как скоро со старта программирования?

Comment: Уже как год  и 2 месяца коммерческой разработки. Попал на работу спустя года обучения. Сейчас учусь каждый день ибо много пропусков, работаю джуном Full Stack .NET Developer. Главное пытаться) и возьмут.