# Есть ли учебные пособия, которые учат сразу писать код для крупных проектов правильно?

Tags: ооп, архитектура, проектирование

Наверняка, многие, кто учил программирование, потом сталкивался с такой проблемой, что учишь-учишь, приходишь на какую-то работу или проект, а там совсем другое программирование. Вроде те же классы и методы, а ничего неясно. Например, я читал и смотрел немало материалов по Java, а потом случайно попался материал, как пишут код на реальном проекте. Оказалось, что даже маленькие приложения там разносятся по энному количеству классов, обязательно навешиваются тесты, поведение программы логируется, используется куча исключений и т. д. Или вот PHP. Полно материалов по основам, а смотришь обзорно "взрослые" проекты, а там все на ООП и фреймворках, которые снова-таки кажутся написанными на каком-то другом PHP. Подозреваю, что все эти корпоративные или промышленные стандарты не из головы берутся, а откуда-то пошли. Откуда? Есть ли какие-то книги, курсы или другие материалы, где сразу учат правильно писать код не для себя, а предприятия с перспективой на многие годы и поддержку кучей людей? Что-то вроде, как пишут код для крупных проектов уровня предприятия. Или хотя бы подскажите, в каком направлении копать, потому что даже примерно не понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

### Разберем на цитаты?

`Есть ли учебные пособия, которые учат сразу писать код для крупных проектов правильно?`

Есть сложные пособия, которые учат писать сложный код для решения сложных проблем. Вопрос в другом: поймете ли вы эти сложные основы без знания основ? Как уже ответил Aziz, вы можете найти книги и по стихам, и по песням, но без знания алфавита вы не осилите ни то, ни другого.

`...приходишь на какую-то работу или проект, а там совсем другое программирование`

Увы, код не везде одинаков. Все программисты пишут по-разному, даже если работают в одной компании и придерживаются одного стиля. Вообще, одну и ту же задачу 2 разных программиста решат по-разному в 99% случаев (только если это не задача A+B).

`Оказалось, что даже маленькие приложения там разносятся по энному количеству классов, обязательно навешиваются тесты, поведение программы логируется, используется куча исключений и т. д.`

В обучающих книгах, видео, курсах начального уровня (уровня "алфавит") учат основам: переменные, функции и возвращаемые значения... На более сложном уровне подключаются перечисления и структуры, дополнительные ресурсы. Затем основы ООП, такие как инкапсуляция, наследование... Чем выше уровень знаний, тем больше возможностей для обучения открыто. Можно постоянно совершенствоваться, так как ничего удивительного в том, что код профессиональных программистов компании отличается от кода в видео/книжках.

`Подозреваю, что все эти корпоративные или промышленные стандарты не из головы берутся, а откуда-то пошли.`

Стандарты - возможно, сюда можно отнести [Паттерны проектирования в ООП](https://habr.com/ru/post/136766/).

`Что-то вроде, как пишут код для крупных проектов уровня предприятия`

Чтобы понять как пишут код на предприятии, нужно там работать... Ведь в разных компаниях его могут писать совсем по-разному!

`Или хотя бы подскажите, в каком направлении копать, потому что даже примерно не понимаю.`

Не знаете основ - учить основы. Знаете основы? Создавайте свои проекты. Но не простые, а челленджевые (о, какое слово), чтобы видеть перед собой проблемы, баги и ошибки и, решая и исправляя их, не стесняться подглядывать в ресурсы/документацию/*StackOverflow* и учиться новому!

**Ну а у нас на стеке есть целая страница с ресурсами по программированию: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по фундаментальным знаниям и навыкам разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474415/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)**. 
Ну и еще здесь "лобби": [Книги и другие материалы для обучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0):

Это примерно сказать. Что в азбуке учат буквы - а есть ли книги или курсы где учат писать стихи, произведения, песни, шедевры одним словом? Нет у каждого промышленного кода есть несколько этапов переписывания и допиливания. Стиль конечно также не сразу у всех вырабатывается на это нужно годы практики.

Comment: Есть книги и по песням, и по стихам итд. Причем там довольно толково рассказывают что и как. Иначе начинаешь смотреть на те же романы. Уверен, в программировании тоже что-то такое есть. Например, как mvc что-то вроде стандарта для фреймворков на php. Понятно, что везде стандарты разные, но какая-то база должна быть.

Comment: @Николай я о том же что они есть и прозаик всех своя. Найдутся ценители и Хейтеры. Ведь цель я думаю не в стандартах. Языков и стандартов много. А MVC и прочие это паттерны как ямб в поэзии.

Comment: Опыт появляется с годами. Не нужно торопиться главное любить и не бояться выбросить свой черновой лист со стихами.