# Книги по системной аналитике и проектированию ПО

Tags: книги, проектирование, аналитика

Посоветуйте хорошие книги по системной аналитике и проектированию ПО. Не хочется сухой теории - хочется, чтобы с примерами и понятным языком для нового человека в данной области. Желательно на русском языке или с переводом.

Хорошей ли для данной области будет книга Стива Макконнелла "Совершенный код"?

Comment: Вигерс. Разработка требований к программному обеспечению

Comment: @RomanKonoval, эта книга 2004 года. Стоит ли?)

Comment: По русски может и не переиздавалась, есть английское издание 2013 года. Стоит или нет - решать вам. Посмотрите отзывы. Издание 2004 было очень хорошее и что касается системного анализа, практически не устарело.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, спасибо за предложение, посмотрю об этой книге

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по фундаментальным знаниям и навыкам разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474415/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)