# Где найти не сведощему вообще в програмированнии базовую информацию

Tags: windows-7

Я F1ve, совсем начинающий программист, я знаю очень мало, лишь int,float,String,bool, char ( прочитал одну статью маленькую, там ничего кроме этого не было. ). Я хочу сначала изучить всю базу, и более, а послее перейти на язык с#.

Comment: Читайте книги, для новичков в том числе. Там есть и база

Comment: Книги рассчитаны на тех у кого уже есть какая-то база, а я даже без неё, мне нужен какой-нибудь ресурс, статья где всё по полкам разложат, что такое case? Почему типом массива может быть int? Мне нужно прям самое начальное.

Comment: Если книги рассчитаны на того, у кого уже есть какая-то база, то откуда, по-вашему, люди черпают базу и черпали базу, когда интернета не было? Из космоса?

Comment: Эмм, из рабочих справочниках, интернет придуман ещё в шестидесятых, для эскплуатации были справочники, что-куда жать, а сейчас технологии другие, образование другое, оно куда обширнее одного справочника, это во первых. А во вторых, даже если так, книг очень много, ту которая подойдёт мне - человеку без каких-либо знаний не легко найти.

Comment: То есть до шестидесятых книг в мире не было?

Comment: По программированию и базовой информации по нему, нет, не думаю.

Comment: Кажется вы придумываете сейчас любые предлоги, чтобы ничему не учиться ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Всмысле, я же спросил, если так думаете, то дайте мне пример книги в которой я получу базу, которая реально для новичков без знаний.

Comment: То есть ссылок с самого первого коммента не достаточно?

Comment: Так мне не язык нужен, мне нужна база конкретно программирования, если только код писать далеко не уедешь.

Comment: А так спасибо за ссылку, но мне не язык нужен пока что, мне до языка далеко.

Comment: Что имеется в виду под "база программирования" ?

Comment: База программирования как по мне - работа с консольными командами, массивы,   операторы,  циклы, классы, и там много чего ещё, и всё это объясняться в лёгкой манере, без терминов, например в той статье где я учил эту информацию, объясняется мало, там приводят лишь пример кода, и пару строк, и то не объясняя многие методы, как break, если что статья Хабр - программирование с нуля.

Comment: В любой книге  (для новичков)  по конкретному языку всё вышеперечисленное вами есть всегда. Т.к. это и есть база любого ЯП (циклы, массивы)... а если учитывать тот факт, что работа с типами может значительно различаться и что в некоторых языках может не быть того, что есть в других языках (например тех же классов или некоторых типов), то поиск каких-то абстрактных тем по "программированию" будет невозможным.......если бы "как работает компьютер внутри", алгоритмы, двоичные и другие системы исчисления и вот это всё - я бы понял....но циклы, типы и пр...это бессмысленно обобщать

Comment: Поэтому в данном случае как раз и надо читать книгу сразу по конкреному языку "для чайников" ................ а так.......... Как минимум идём сюда  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/книги?tab=Votes
  .........
(фундаментальный навык разработчика: уметь искать информацию... вот вам первый урок....на каждом сайте для начала используйте поиск))))
  ...........
Дальше можно заглянуть сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474415   .....сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683 .... и т.д.... всё это ссылки из певоначального списка

Comment: Про алгоритмы я тоже имел в виду, я совсем нуб, и не понимаю, что вам понятно.

Comment: Вам для начала надо определиться в каком направлении двигаться. Потому что в некоторых направлениях разработки некоторые знания абсолютно бесполезны.....как правило для написания  страниц html вам вряд ли понядобится машинное обучение (во всяком случае на начальных этапах, а может быть и вообще никогда). В разработке игр математика, алгоритмы, физика и геометрия очень нужны, в то время как, опять же, при создании какого-нибудь блога - алгоритмы не нужны. и т.д. Т.е. изучить всё всё всё ради сферического коня в вакууме...ну такое..............а так. ссылки выше