# Книги и учебные ресурсы по языку R

Tags: книги, r, faq

Рекомендуемая литература, курсы и документация по языку R.

- Не создавайте новых ответов — редактируйте общий ответ.
- Не размещайте ссылки на нелегальный контент, вроде торрент-трекеров.
- Старайтесь сохранять разделение по категориям.

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Литература

#### Русский

- А.Б. Шипунов, Е.М. Балдин, П.А. Волкова и др.: Наглядная статистика. Используем R! (*ISBN: 978-5-97060-094-8*)

  - [Бесплатная электронная версия](http://ashipunov.info/shipunov/school/books/rbook.pdf) (Книга передана в общественное достояние)
  - [Исходные тексты LaTeX](http://ashipunov.info/shipunov/software/r/src.tar.gz)
- Роберт И. Кабаков: R в действии. Анализ и визуализация данных на языке R (перевод с английского, *ISBN: 978-1-93518-239-9, 978-5-94074-912-7, 978-5-97060-077-1*)
- [Дуглас Люк: Анализ сетей (графов) в среде R. Руководство пользователя. Цветное издание.](http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/statistics/978-5-97060-428-1/) (перевод с английского, *ISBN: 978-5-97060-428-1* )
- [Джеймс Г., Уиттон Д., Хасти Т., Тибширани Р.: Введение в статистическое обучение с примерами на языке R. Цветное издание.](http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/statistics/978-5-97060-293-5/) (перевод с английского, *ISBN: 978-5-97060-293-5* )
- Мастицкий С.Э., Шитиков В.К.: Статистический анализ и визуализация данных с помощью R (*ISBN: 978-5-97060-301-7*)

  - [Бесплатная электронная версия](https://github.com/ranalytics/r-tutorials/blob/master/Edition_2014/Book/Mastitsky_and_Shitikov_2014_R_tutorials.pdf) ([CC BY-NC-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/deed.ru))
  - [Репозиторий автора на GitHub, с примерами к книге](https://github.com/ranalytics/r-tutorials)
  - [Блог автора](http://r-analytics.blogspot.ru/)
- Шитиков В.К., Мастицкий С.Э. Классификация, регрессия и другие алгоритмы Data Mining с использованием R

  - [Бесплатная электронная версия](http://www.ievbras.ru/ecostat/Kiril/R/DM/DM_R.pdf) ([CC BY-NC-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/deed.ru))
  - [Репозиторий автора на GitHub, с примерами к книге](https://github.com/ranalytics/data-mining)

#### English:

- [Список англоязычной литературы на официальном сайте R-project](https://www.r-project.org/doc/bib/R-books.html)

## Сетевые ресурсы

#### Документация и онлайн литература

**Русский:**

- [Викиучебник: Язык программирования R](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_R)
- [Статьи по R на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/hub/r/)
- А. Б. Шипунов, Е. М. Балдин: [Анализ данных с R](http://www.inp.nsk.su/~baldin/DataAnalysis/index.html) (сборник статей, изданных в журнале Linux Format, электронная версия с  сайта автора)
- Девид Мертц, Бред Хантинг: Статистическое программирование на R (электронный перевод, части [1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-r1/index.html), [2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-r2/index.html), [3](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-r3/index.html))
- Перевод документации по пакетам [dplyr](https://github.com/statist-bhfz/dplyr_doc_ru), [tidyr](https://github.com/statist-bhfz/dplyr_doc_ru/blob/master/tidy_data/tidy_data.Rmd), [data.table](https://github.com/statist-bhfz/data.table_doc_ru) ([руководство по data.table на bookdown.org](https://bookdown.org/statist_/DataTableManual/))

**English:**

- [CRAN Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/): обзоры пакетов R по определеным направлениям от лучших разработчиков.
- [Официальный мануал от разработчиков](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html)
- [Шпаргалки (примеры кода) от RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/)
- [Cookbook - примеры решения распространенных задач](http://www.cookbook-r.com/)
- [Quick-R (Блог)](http://www.statmethods.net)
- [R-Bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/): сайт, куда стекаются посты из сотен блогов, общее - использование R.
- [The R Inferno: описание того, как не стоит делать в R и как стоит](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)
- [Bookdown](https://bookdown.org/): сайт, который хостит книги, написанные с помощью пакета `bookdown`. Разумеется, первые книги - сплошные сокровища по освоению и использованию R.
- [Awesome R](https://github.com/qinwf/awesome-R)
- [Advanced R by Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/)
- [R Data Science Tutorials](https://github.com/ujjwalkarn/DataScienceR)
- [R for Data Science (Garrett Grolemund, Hadley Wickham)](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/)

#### Онлайн курсы

**Русский:**

- [Stepic: Анализ данных в R](https://stepic.org/course/129)
- [Stepic: Основы программирования на R](https://stepic.org/course/497)

  - [Репозиторий автора на GitHub, с кодом и данными](https://github.com/tonytonov/Rcourse)
- [Stepic: Анализ данных в R. Часть 2](https://stepik.org/course/724)

**English:**

- [Coursera: R Programming](https://www.coursera.org/learn/r-programming) (входит в специализацию [Data Science](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/jhu-data-science))
- [Data Camp: Introduction to R](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/free-introduction-to-r)
- [Udacity: Data Analysis with R. Visually Analyze and Summarize Data Sets](https://www.udacity.com/course/data-analysis-with-r--ud651)
- [Code School: Try R](http://tryr.codeschool.com/)

#### Интерактивное обучение

- [swirl](http://swirlstats.com/): R пакет для интерактивного обучения (см. русскоязычный материал [на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/271265/))

Comment: http://prnt.sc/4jxgoi

Comment: Я тут добавил ссылки на свои переводы виньеток по dplyr, tidyr и data.table, и подумал: а что, если скооперироваться и осилить перевод официальных мануалов https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html, особенно The R language definition? Вот это руководство я бы сам перевел, если бы мне хотя бы с вычиткой помогли.

Comment: @Ogurtsov Давайте попробуем на том же ГитХабе скооперироваться, не вижу проблемы. Для общения на тему перевода создан чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37639/r Завтра возможно подтянется ещё один участник.

Comment: [Здесь](https://github.com/bdemeshev/em301/wiki/R) тоже полно ссылок, но их нужно проверять.

Comment: Добавил ссылку на http://r4ds.had.co.nz/ - очень годная книга (еще не совсем готова, но вроде бы и окончательный вариант будет в свободном доступе).