# Книги и учебные ресурсы по Linux

Tags: linux, книги, faq

Рекомендуемая литература, курсы и документация по Linux.

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Comment: а почему бы всё-таки не поместить этот список в описание метки (как, вроде бы, рекомендует устоявшаяся практика)?

Comment: Прошу пояснить, как добавить и куда?

Comment: щёлкаете по метке, далее по ссылке «подробнее», для метки, например, «linux», попадёте [сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/linux/info). но прежде чем редактировать, неплохо ознакомиться с описаниями [других популярных меток](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Начинающим**

- *Linux. От новичка к профессионалу*,  Денис Колисниченко, БХВ-Петербург,    2016, ISBN:     978-5-9775-3700-1

*Официальная документация:*

- Slackware: [*SlackBook*](http://www.slackbook.org/)
- RedHat/Centos: [*RedHat System Administrator's guide*](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7-Beta/html/System_Administrators_Guide/index.html) - на середину
  2016 года, содержит лучшее руководство по управлению systemd.
- SuSE: [*SLES 12 Administration guide*](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-12/book_sle_admin/data/book_sle_admin.html)
- Ubuntu: [*Ubuntubook. Установка и настройка.*](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0/ubuntubook)
- [*Курс подготовки к экзамену LPIC-1. Основы linux.*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/078214425X)  Rodrick W.
  Smith, 2005
- [Отличный гайд по скриптованию на bash](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf)

**Средний уровень**

- *Linux Kernel Development  (3rd Edition)*,  Robert Love, Addison-Wesley Professional, 2010, ISBN: 978-0-6723-2946-3

  Русский перевод: *Ядро Linux. Описание процесса разработки*, Роберт Лав, Вильямс, 2014, ISBN: 978-5-8459-1944-1
- *How Linux Works: What Every Superuser Should Know* -Brian Word

Русский перевод :   [Внутреннее устройство linux](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/34792459/) - Брайан Уорд

- *The book of Postfix : state-of-the-art message transport* - Ralf
  Hildebrandt and Patrick Koetter

Русский перевод: [Postfix. Подробное руководство](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3925535/)

- Очень крутой сборник рецептов linux и чуть-чуть powershell.  [*RTFM
  (Red Team Field Manual)*](https://watchthestack.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/rtfm-red-team-field-manual.pdf)

**Продвинутый уровень**

- *Computer Networks 5th Edition Aandrew Tanenbaum, David Wetherall*

[Книга](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7309924/) подробно рассказывает про сети в ОС UNIX, уровни модели OSI, сетевую безопасность. Также [Онлайн](http://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/1039398/Tanenbaum_-_Kompyuternye_seti._5-e_izdanie.html) можно прочитать.

**Linux для встраиваемых систем**

- *Mastering Embedded Linux Programming: Harness the Power of Linux To Create Versatile and Robust Embedded Solutions*, Chris Simmonds, Packt Publishing Ltd., 2015, ISBN: 978-1-7843-9902-3

  Русский перевод: Встраиваемые системы на основе Linux. Крис Симмондс, ДМК Пресс, 2017, ISBN: 978-5-97060-483-0

**Онлайн курсы:**

- Введение в linux (Превосходный курс для новичков)
  https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-linux-linuxfoundationx-lfs101x-0
- Платный, но очень неплохой русскоязычный курс для начального уровня
  http://www.specialist.ru/course/yun1-b
- Русскоязычный курс по linux
  [https://stepik.org/course/Введение-в-Linux-73/](https://stepik.org/course/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Linux-73/)

Comment: судя по названиям, **действительно** про linux рассказывается разве что в книге «внутреннее устройство linux», да и там, судя по оглавлению, linux-у уделяется лишь небольшая часть книги.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я думаю, что этот и другие вопросы нужно переименовывать.
В основном эти книги об операционной системе GNU.
Компьютерная граммотность снижается из-за неправильных названий, таких как: Операционная система GNU и ядро Linux; Виртуальная консоль и эмулятор терминала.
Может поднять этот вопрос на Мете ?