# Посоветуйте актуальную книгу по ядру не устаревшей версии Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel

Доброго времени суток. Перед созданием вопроса пользовался поиском. Подобного не нашел.

Посоветуйте актуальную книгу по устройству и разработке linux kernel. На SO уже советовали Р. Лава, но его книга по ядру описывает 2.6 версию. 
Есть ли подобная по 4.8 версии или не менее релевантная, выпущенная в течение года.

Comment: Это хороший повод, чтобы подумать о том, чтобы написать такую книгу самому.:)

Comment: в прогрессе, можете поучаствовать: https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/index.html

Comment: Боюсь единственная актуальная книга по ядру - это исходники ядра

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow , это вы конечно хорошо пошутили, а серьезно?

Comment: @Mike , просто читать исходники будет сложно и не понятно для меня на данный момент

Comment: @R.Pavlov В каждой шутке есть доля истины. Лучший способ изучить предмет - это написать книгу о предмете.:)

Comment: @R.Pavlov Ядро быстро развивается, даже внутри одной ветки. даже если кто то напишет актуальную книгу, за время ее печати в типографии поменяются десятки структур и функций. причем часть важных интерфейсов могут кардинально измениться.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, качество хорошее, но хватит ли этого или придется еще что-то почитовать? Дайте пожалуйста еще полезных ссылок, если есть.
Я в свою очередь даю [ссылку на браузер файлов ядра](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source)

Comment: ну что значит "хватит ли этого" - смотря на каком уровне вы хотите знать ядро и зачем вам это нужно. Подкину сюда ссылок еще, если вспомню, но в целом - там больше уже работа с подсистемами - одно на другое заменить и посмотреть как оно работает, с гипервизорами и т.д.

Comment: для желающих ответить: лучше внести информацию в описание метки: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/linux/info

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Linux](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582544/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-linux)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , там вопрос про документацию. И все книги в том ответе старые.

Comment: (мимо проходя, selectel требует почту, но nieploho на первый взгляд про дебаги ядра)  https://selectel.ru/promo/wp-trassirovka-profilirovanie-yadra-linux-vvedenie/

Comment: Читаете любую книгу, про любую версию ядра, для понимания общей концепции, затем настольный справочник http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ и практическая работа. Как правильно сказали, книги быстро устаревают.

Comment: Linux internals. https://github.com/0xAX/linux-insides