# Какую книжку для изучения основ С с нуля выбрать?

Tags: c

Посоветуйте,пожалуйста,какую книжку для изучения основ С с нуля? Чтобы были подробно разобраны основы.

Comment: @R Georgy Сейчас все бросятся рекомендовать книгу Брайана Кернигана и Денниса Ритчи "Язык программирования C", но на мой взгляд она для уже подготовленного читателя. Думаю, вам надо что-то другое.:)

Comment: «Бросятся» закрывать вопрос и ставить минусы, скорее всего, хотя подробного ответа, [**как для других языков программирования**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454684/199934) для `C` на этом сайте нет. Спасибо.

Comment: Если самые основы, то можно начать с книги [«Код. Тайный язык информатики» Чарльз Петцольд](https://livelib.ru/book/1000005181/reviews-kod-tajnyj-yazyk-informatiki-charlz-pettsold)—одна из лучших книг, чтобы узнать как компьютеры работают.

Comment: для желающих дать ответ: лучше дополнить список литературы в описании метки — http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info

Comment: @СашаЧерных Было бы здорово, если бы кто–либо опубликовал подобный вопрос. Что скажите?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я могу ошибаться, но процедура для составления списка литературы/ресурсов для метки: 1. опубликовать канонический вопрос (всё остальное закрыть как дубликат/удалить) 2. Опубликовать ответы (одна книга на ответ) 3. Когда голосование явно определит популярный выбор (через год/два), тогда собрать все популярные ответы в один общий ответ и удалить старые ответы, заблокировать вопрос. Не уверен об обновлениях, хотя хорошие книги остаются хорошими десятилетиями (об основах): C.O.D.E, SICP, K&R, Code Complete, Unix Programming Environment, [etc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1711/4279)

Comment: @jfs, увы, невнимательно слежу за обсуждениями на meta. но список литературы в описании метки выглядит достаточно разумно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin безусловно, конечный результат (список) имеет смысл в описание меток помещать, но вопросы/ответы позволяют голосование/комментарии использовать в одном месте и понизить барьер для новых предложений.

Answer (score 1):

Совсем с нуля? "[Программирование на C для чайников](http://www.dialektika.com/books/978-5-8459-2074-4.html)"

Как большой справочник - "[C in a Nutshell](http://shtonda.blogspot.com/2016/08/c11-in-nutshell-prinz-crawford.html)"