# Книги и учебные ресурсы по машинному обучению

Tags: математика, книги, машинное-обучение

Посоветуйте какие-нибудь хорошие книги по математике и машинному обучению. Желательно в доступной для понимания форме.

Дописывайте, если есть что добавить в общий ответ.

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683).

Answer (score 93):

Прежде чем заниматься конкретно машинным обучением, рекомендуем ознакомиться с книгами

- Стюарт Рассел, Питер Норвиг ***Искусственный интеллект. Современный
  подход*** [источник](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31336425/)
- Джордж Ф. Люгер ***Искусственный интеллект. Стратегии и методы

  решения сложных проблем*** [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/29128610/)

таким образом у вас сформируется более четкое понимание предметной области машинного обучения и сильно расширит ваш кругозор.
Нейронные сети занимают важную позицию в машинном обучении, поэтому стоит ознакомиться с книгой

- Саймон Хайкин ***Нейронные сети. Полный курс*** [источник](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/135794246/)

Также вы должны уметь производить предварительный анализ данных, чтобы понять, какие методы машинного обучения можно применить к вашему набору данных или как его лучше подготовить, в этом вам помогут следующие книги:

- *Борис Миркин* **Введение в анализ данных. Учебник и практикум**
  [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31276096/)
- *Марина Архипова, Татьяна Дуброва* **Анализ данных. Учебник**
  [источник](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/138891800/)
- *Загоруйко Н.Г.* **Прикладные методы анализа данных и знаний** [источник](http://www.twirpx.com/file/1207783/)
- *Мостеллер Ф., Тьюки Дж.* **Анализ данных и регрессия** [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/28906275/)
- *Рубан А.И.* **Методы анализа данных**
- *Уэс Маккинни* **Python и анализ данных** [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/32719186/) (практика)
- *Роберт И. Кабаков*  **R в действии. Анализ и визуализация данных на языке R** [источник](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/136073963/) (практика)

Вы должны знать хорошо математику (в особенности линейную алгебру), статистику, теорию вероятностей, дискретную математику. Я, например, неважно знаю математику и мне очень тяжело читать стандартные учебники, рассчитанные на то, что преподаватель сможет разжевать скупое описание формулы, поэтому для легкого порога вхождения рекомендую следующие книги (от основ и выше):

- *Стивен Х. Строгац* **Удовольствие от x. Увлекательная экскурсия в мир математики от одного из лучших преподавателей в мире** [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/26014221/)
- *Юрий Шиханович* **Введение в современную математику. Начальные понятия** [источник](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7245110/)
- *Рональд Л. Грэхем, Дональд Эрвин Кнут* **Конкретная математика. Математические основы информатики** [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31333006/)
- *Юрий Пухначев* **Математика без формул** [книга1](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/138398056/), [книга2](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/140488633/)
- Тарасов Л.В. **Азбука математического анализа. Беседы об основных понятиях. Учебное пособие** [источник](http://urss.ru/cgi-bin/db.pl?lang=Ru&blang=ru&page=Book&id=192170)
- *Анатолий Мышкис* **Лекции по высшей математике** [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3557941/)
- *Рихард Курант, Герберт Роббинс* **Что такое математика?** [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/34095830/)

Потом уже можно браться за стандартный учебник математического анализа

- *Фихтенгольц Г.М.* **Основы математического анализа** [источник](http://publ.lib.ru/ARCHIVES/F/FIHTENGOL%27C_Grigoriy_Mihaylovich/_Fihtengol%27c_G.M..html)

## Книги на русском языке

- *Петер Флах* **Машинное обучение** [источник](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/data/978-5-97060-273-7/), [Оглавление и отрывки из глав](https://dmkpress.com/files/PDF/978-5-97060-273-7.pdf)
- *Кристофер М. Бишоп* **Распознавание образов и машинное обучение** [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/product/raspoznavanie-obrazov-i-mashinnoe-obuchenie-180548800/)
- *Джеймс Г., Уиттон Д., Хасти Т., Тибширани Р.* **Введение в статистическое обучение с примерами на языке R** [источник](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/statistics/978-5-97060-293-5/), [Оглавление и отрывки из глав](https://dmkpress.com/files/PDF/978-5-97060-293-5.pdf)
- *Себастьян Рашка* **Python и машинное обучение** [источник](http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/data/978-5-97060-409-0/)
- *Хенрик Бринк, Джозеф Ричардс* **Машинное обучение** [источник](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/140959418/)
- *Хараламбос Марманис, Дмитрий Бабенко* **Алгоритмы интеллектуального Интернета. Передовые методики сбора, анализа и обработки данных** [источник](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6753996/)
- *К. В. Воронцов* **Математические методы обучения по прецедентам (теория обучения машин)** [источник](http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/images/6/6d/Voron-ML-1.pdf)
- *Мерков А.Б.* **Введение в методы статистического обучения** [источник](http://urss.ru/cgi-bin/db.pl?lang=Ru&blang=ru&page=Book&id=116135)
- *Аркадий Гелиг, Алексей Матвеев* **Введение в математическую теорию обучаемых распознающих систем и нейронных сетей. Учебное пособие** [источник](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/32989014/)
- *Мерков А.Б.* **Построение и обучение вероятностных моделей** [источник](http://urss.ru/cgi-bin/db.pl?lang=Ru&blang=ru&page=Book&id=169378)
- *Ричарт В., Коэльо П.Л.* **Построение систем машинного обучения на языке Python** [источник](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/python/978-5-97060-330-7/), [Оглавление и отрывки из глав](https://dmkpress.com/files/PDF/978-5-97060-330-7.pdf) (тут больше практика по машинному обучению)
- *Вьюгин В.* **Математические основы машинного обучения и прогнозирования** [источник](http://iitp.ru/upload/publications/6256/vyugin1.pdf)
- *Червоненкис А.Я.* **Теория обучения машин**
- *Ричард С. Саттон, Эндрю Г. Барто*  **Обучение с подкреплением** [источник](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7107485/)
- *Андреас Мюллер, Сара Гвидо* **Введение в машинное обучение с помощью Python. Руководство для специалистов по работе с данными** [источник](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/140891479/)
- *Дэви Силен, Арно Мейсман* **Основы Data Science и Big Data. Python и наука о данных** [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/139191940/)
- *Лепский А.Е., Броневич А.Г.* **Математические методы распознавания образов: Курс лекций** [источник](http://window.edu.ru/resource/800/73800/files/lect_Lepskiy_Bronevich_pass.pdf)
- *В. И. Донской* **Алгоритмические модели обучения классификации:обоснование, сравнение, выбор** [источник](http://ta.cfuv.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/donskoj.pdf)
- *Местецкий Л.М.* **Математические методы распознавания образов Курс лекций** [источник](http://www.ccas.ru/frc/papers/mestetskii04course.pdf)
- *Кристофер Д. Маннинг, Прабхакар Рагхаван* **Введение в информационный поиск** [источник](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5497130/)
- *Юре Лесковец, Ананд Раджараман* **Анализ больших наборов данных** [источник](http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/data/978-5-97060-190-7/), [оглавление и отрывки из глав](http://dmkpress.com/files/PDF/978-5-97060-190-7.pdf)
- *Гудфеллоу Я., Бенджио И., Курвилль А.* **Глубокое обучение** [источник](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/data/978-5-97060-618-6/), [оглавление и отрывки из глав](http://dmkpress.com/files/PDF/978-5-97060-554-7.pdf)
- *Шлезингер М.И.* **Десять лекций по статистическому и структурному распознаванию образов** [источник](http://irtc.org.ua/image/Files/Schles/esh10_full.pdf)
- *Джулли А., Пал С.* **Библиотека Keras — инструмент глубокого обучения** [источник](http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/data/978-5-97060-573-8/) [оглавление и отрывки из глав](http://dmkpress.com/files/PDF/978-5-97060-573-8.pdf)
- *Шарден Б., Массарон Л., Боскетти А.* **Крупномасштабное машинное обучение вместе с Python** [источник](http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/data/978-5-97060-506-6/) [оглавление и отрывки из глав](http://dmkpress.com/files/PDF/978-5-97060-506-6-1.pdf)
- *Шитиков В.К., Мастицкий С.Э.* **Классификация, регрессия и другие алгоритмы Data Mining с использованием R** [источник](http://www.ievbras.ru/ecostat/Kiril/R/DM/DM_R.pdf) , [эл.версия](https://ranalytics.github.io/data-mining/)
- *Дж. Вандер Плас* **Python для сложных задач. Наука о данных и машинное обучение** [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/142007330/)
- *Даррен Кук* **Машинное обучение с использованием библиотеки Н2О** [источник](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/data/978-5-97060-508-0/)  [оглавление и отрывки из глав](https://dmkpress.com/files/PDF/978-5-97060-508-0.pdf)
- **Открытый курс OpenDataScience по машинному обучению** [источник - статьи на Хабрахабре](https://github.com/Yorko/mlcourse_open)
- **Слайды лекций по курсу “Машинное обучение”**  [источник](http://www.levvu.narod.ru/EdProcess.htm)
- Лекция 2008 года *Н.Ю. Золотых* **Как обучаются машины?** [источник](http://www.uic.unn.ru/%7Ezny/ml/Others/ml_pop.pdf), [презентация к лекциям от 2018 г.](http://www.uic.unn.ru/%7Ezny/ml/Course/ml_pres.pdf)
- *Тарик Рашид* **Создаем нейронную сеть** [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/141796497/)
- *Николенко С. И., Кадурин А. А., Архангельская Е. О.* **Глубокое обучение** [источник](https://www.piter.com/collection/soon/product/glubokoe-obuchenie)
- *С. И. Николенко, А. Л. Тулупьев* **Самообучающиеся системы** [источник](https://www.litres.ru/aleksandr-tulupev/samoobuchauschiesya-sistemy-11647871/)
- *Паттерсон Дж., Гибсон А.* **Глубокое обучение с точки зрения практика** [источник](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/data/978-5-97060-481-6/), [оглавление и отрывки из глав](https://dmkpress.com/files/PDF/978-5-97060-481-6.pdf)
- *Хейдт М.* **Изучаем pandas** [источник](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/python/978-5-97060-625-4/), [оглавление и отрывки из глав](https://dmkpress.com/files/PDF/978-5-97060-625-4.pdf)
- *Орельен Жерон* **Прикладное машинное обучение с помощью Scikit-Learn и TensorFlow. Концепции, инструменты и техники для
  создания интеллектуальных систем** [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/144106127/), [оглавление](https://ozon-st.cdn.ngenix.net/multimedia/1021976147.pdf),
  [отрывки из глав](https://ozon-st.cdn.ngenix.net/multimedia/1021976149.pdf)
- *П.Е. Овчинников* **Применение искусственных нейронных сетей для обработки сигналов. Учебно-методическое пособие.** 2012г
  [источник](http://window.edu.ru/resource/846/77846/files/Ovch_ANN.pdf)
- *Франсуа Шолле* **Глубокое обучение на R**  [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/146089453/), [оглавление](https://ozon-st.cdn.ngenix.net/multimedia/1023471543.pdf), [отрывки из глав](https://ozon-st.cdn.ngenix.net/multimedia/1023471544.pdf)
- *О`Нил, Шатт* **Data Science. Инсайдерская информация для новичков. Включая язык R** [источник](https://www.labirint.ru/books/667268/)
- *Шай Шалев-Шварц, Шай Бен-Давид* **Идеи машинного обучения** [источник](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/data/978-5-97060-673-5/), [оглавление и отрывки из глав](https://dmkpress.com/files/PDF/978-5-97060-673-5.pdf)
- *Франсуа Шолле* **Глубокое обучение на Python** [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/145615583/)
- *Пратик Джоши* **Искусственный интеллект с примерами на Python** [источник](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-907114-41-8.html)
- *Бенгфорт Б., Билбро Р., Охеда Т.* **Прикладной анализ текстовых данных на Python. Машинное обучение и создание приложений обработки
  естественного языка** [источник](https://www.piter.com/collection/new/product/prikladnoy-analiz-tekstovyh-dannyh-na-python-mashinnoe-obuchenie-i-sozdanie-prilozheniy-obrabotki-estestvennogo-yazyka)
- *Келлехер Дж., Мак-Нейми Б., д`Арси А.* **Основы машинного обучения для
  аналитического прогнозирования: алгоритмы, рабочие примеры и
  тематические исследования** [источник](https://www.chitai-gorod.ru/catalog/book/1172490/)
- *Равичандиран С.* **Глубокое обучение с подкреплением на Python. OpenAI Gym и TensorFlow для профи** [источник](https://www.piter.com/collection/bestsellery-packt/product/glubokoe-obuchenie-s-podkrepleniem-na-python-openai-gym-i-tensorflow-dlya-profi)

## Видео на русском языке

- Высшая школа экономики *«Введение в машинное
  обучение»* [источник Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/vvedenie-mashinnoe-obuchenie)
- Специализация *Машинное обучение и анализ данных* включающая себя 6
  курсов : [источник Coursera](https://ru.coursera.org/specializations/machine-learning-data-analysis)
- Видеолекции курса *«Машинное обучение»* от Школы анализа данных Яндекса [источник на яндексе](https://yandexdataschool.ru/edu-process/courses/machine-learning) или [источник на ютубе](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLBkB4sMztk&list=PLJOzdkh8T5kp99tGTEFjH_b9zqEQiiBtC)
- Специализация *Анализ Данных* от [Stepik](http://data.stepik.org/details) (часть курсов из этой
  специализации отображена тут)
- Курс Р.В. Шамина *Машинное обучение и искусственный интеллект в математике и приложениях* [источник](http://www.mathnet.ru/conf1243)
- Виктор Кантор МФТИ *Машинное обучение* [источник](http://lectoriy.mipt.ru/course/MachineLearning-L#lectures)
- Курс от Stepik *Нейронные сети* [источник](https://stepik.org/course/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-401)
- Видеолекциии (13шт.) *Введение в анализ данных* [источник
  Mail.ru](https://sphere.mail.ru/materials/video/#6)
- Видеолекциии (1 семестр) *Data Minig* [источник Mail.ru](https://sphere.mail.ru/materials/video/#7)
- Видеолекциии (2 семестр) *Data Minig* [источник Mail.ru](https://sphere.mail.ru/materials/video/#12)
- Computer Science Center *Машинное обучение, часть 1* (осень 2016)
  [источник ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlb7e2G7aSpSWVExpq74FnwFnWgLby56L)
- Computer Science Center *Машинное обучение, часть 2* (весна 2017)
  [источник ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlb7e2G7aSpSSsCeUMLN-RxYOLAI9l2ld)
- Data Mining in Action *10 лекций по ML* [источник ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCop3CelRVvrchG5lsPyxvHg)
- Компьютерные науки *Тренировки Machine Learning* [источник
  ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJOzdkh8T5kqpk3XNAqg3hawCuteiNoXX) здесь люди делятся своим реальным опытом в ML
- Шамин Р.В. *Лекции по искусственному интеллекту и машинному обучению* [источник](http://ai.lector.ru/?go=video)
- Искусственный интеллект и машинное обучение (лекции) [источник - сайт](https://ulearn.azurewebsites.net/Course/AIML/), [ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfelJa0QlJWwPEZ6XNbNRyA/playlists)
- Канал *OpenDataScience по машинному обучению и MLClass* [источник ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgGADKKGalfwSNbpSyM5ryg)
- Сергей Николенко *Основы байесовского вывода* [источник ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVm6LKr9rLY&list=PL-_cKNuVAYAU0vPERG07V2B_fykSxiL7z&index=1)
- Технострим Mail.Ru *Нейронные сети в машинном обучении (осень 2017)* [источник](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am82yvUSwRE&list=PLrCZzMib1e9oOGNLh6_d65HyfdqlJwTQP)
- Андрей Созыкин Онлайн курс *Программирование глубоких нейронных сетей
  на Python* источник [сайт](https://www.asozykin.ru/courses/nnpython), [ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GX7qxV5nh5o&list=PLtPJ9lKvJ4oiz9aaL_xcZd-x0qd8G0VN_)
- Биофармкластер «Северный» *Машинное обучение* 11 лекций на тему ML
  [источник ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/user/biopharmcluster/search?query=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), к сожалению отдельного плейлиста нет, поэтому
  придется лекции не найденные через поиск искать в общем плейлисте самому.
- Курс на 9 недель от ВШЭ и Яндекса *Practical Reinforcement
  Learning* (сами видео лекций и практических семинаров на русском
  языке найдете в разделе Materials каждой недели) [источник github](https://github.com/yandexdataschool/Practical_RL)
- *Информационный поиск* (осень 2016) [источник](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlb7e2G7aSpQJH3UefgoBBxkCz0xn2R3x)
- Ивахненко А.А. *Введение в теорию нейросетей и глубокое обучение*
  [источник](https://compscicenter.ru/courses/neural-networks/2017-autumn/classes/)
- Python для анализа данных [источник Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-for-data-science)
- Семинары по машинному обучению JetBrains Research [источник](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdeSxuESqLOxuuwXNnqqbrA/videos)

## Онлайн курсы, видеокурсы по математике и статистике

- Высшая школа экономики, курс *Линейная алгебра* [источник Coursera](https://ru.coursera.org/learn/algebra-lineynaya)
- Лекториум *Линейная алгебра и аналитическая геометрия* [источник
  ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-_cKNuVAYAXCJa9WsBu0wrwtPW4L2FFH)
- Лекторий МФТИ *Линейная алгебра* [источник](http://lectoriy.mipt.ru/course/LinearAlgebra#lectures)
- МФТИ, курс *Теория вероятностей для начинающих* [источник
  Coursera](https://ru.coursera.org/learn/probability-theory-basics)
- МФТИ, курс *Математика для всех* [источник Coursera](https://ru.coursera.org/learn/matematika-dlya-vseh)
- Курс от Stepik *Основы статистики* [часть1](https://stepik.org/course/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-76/syllabus),[часть2](https://stepik.org/course/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-2-524/), [часть3](https://stepik.org/course/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-3-2152/)
- Курс от Stepik *Математическая статистика* [источник](https://stepik.org/course/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-326/)
- Курс от Stepik *Введение в дискретную математику* [источник](https://stepik.org/course/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-902/)
- Курс от Stepik *Ликбез по дискретной математике* [источник](https://stepik.org/course/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-91/)
- Курс от Stepik *Введение в математический анализ* [источник](https://stepik.org/course/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7-95/)
- Курс от Stepik *Математический анализ* [часть1](https://stepik.org/course/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7-%28%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-1%29-716/), [часть2](https://stepik.org/course/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7-%28%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-2%29-711/)
- Курс от Stepik *Анализ данных в R* [часть1](https://stepik.org/course/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-R-129/), [часть2](https://stepik.org/course/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-R-%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-2-724/)
- Computer Science Center *Анализ данных на R в примерах и задачах*
  (весна 2016) [источник ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlb7e2G7aSpSSa_PlFEwnd6-3gzAa08_m)
- Computer Science Center *Анализ данных на R в примерах и задачах,
  часть 2* (весна 2017) [источник ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlb7e2G7aSpTh7pQG8ek1Uv5-zatv84vY)
- Канал на ютубе *Основы анализа данных* [источник](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLk-Oih8VlqF-StidijTUnw/featured)
- KhanAcademyRussian *Теор. вероятн-ей и комбинаторика* [источник
  ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxGo9dxQkqWCwwG8YLBkc86eOE7ER0LcE)
- *Алгебра* (133видео) [источник KhanAcademyRussian](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCB7E37537330650A)
- Р.В. Шамин. *Математический анализ - лекции* [источник](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEaWFQiR5rGNu4wpf2oFXcmyraLCMvfzR)
- кружок от ФПМИ МФТИ *Школа глубокого обучения* [ютуб](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFTNoZYjkg-3LZTHrHfV1nQ/), [github](https://github.com/DLSchool/dlschool), [git2](https://github.com//deepmipt/dlschl)

## На любителя:

- Занимательная статистика. Манга. http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/statistics/978-5-94120-269-0
- Занимательная статистика. Регрессионный анализ. Манга http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/statistics/978-5-97060-115-0
- Занимательная математика. Производные и интегралы. Манга http://dmkpress.com/catalog/manga/978-5-94120-228-7/
- Занимательная статистика. Факторный анализ. Манга http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/statistics/978-5-97060-116-7

## Статистика, теория вероятностей:

- *Гнеденко Б.В., Хинчин А.Я.* **Элементарное введение в теорию вероятностей** [источник](http://urss.ru/cgi-bin/db.pl?lang=Ru&blang=ru&page=Book&id=212605)
- *Владимир Савельев* **Статистика и котики** [источник](https://ridero.ru/books/statistika_i_kotiki/), [немного почитать](http://www.statcats.ru/p/blog-page_29.html)
- *Сара Бослаф* **Статистика для всех** [источник](http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/statistics/978-5-94074-969-1/)
- *Чарльз Уилан* **Голая статистика. Самая интересная книга о самой скучной науке** [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/135537331/)
- *Эндрю Брюс, Питер Брюс*  **Практическая статистика для специалистов Data Science** [источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/145995607/) , [оглавление и фрагмент книги](https://ozon-st.cdn.ngenix.net/multimedia/1023435350.pdf)
- *Дж. Хей* **Введение в методы байесовского статистического вывода** [источник](http://urss.ru/cgi-bin/db.pl?lang=Ru&blang=ru&page=Book&id=99516)
- *Дауни А.Б.* **Байесовские модели** [источник](https://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/python/978-5-97060-664-3), [оглавление и отрывки](https://dmkpress.com/files/PDF/978-5-97060-664-3.pdf)

Перечень будет периодически дополняться.

Comment: Очень большой список. Совершенно не представляю с чего начать. А можно добавить отдельный список для начинающих? Простые обзорные книги, чтобы можно было сперва сориентироваться, а потом уже изучать более углублённо.

Comment: Тогда вам стоит начать с курса Высшей школы экономики «Введение в машинное обучение», а дальше уже сами сориентируетесь. Критерий "для начинающих" всё же сильно субъективен, т.к. кто то хочет иметь сильную теоретическую базу, а кто то сразу с практики хочет заняться.

Answer (score 42):

**Топ лучших бесплатных книг по машинному обучению:**

---

- The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction.
  В этой книге авторы попытались объединить много важных новых идей, связанных со статистическим обучением. Хотя в книге не хватает математических деталей, авторы неплохо объясняют именно основы концептов. Книга пригодится не только специалистам по статистике, но и людям, работающим в смежных областях.
- Introduction To Machine Learning. Цель этой книги — введение в индуктивное логическое программирование, раздел науки на стыке машинного обучения и логического программирования. Книга будет полезна тем, кто изучает принципы работы с базами данных, дата-инжиниринг, ИИ, машинное обучение и логическое программирование.
- Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction. Обучение с подкреплением — это один из способов машинного обучения, в ходе которого испытуемая система взаимодействует с некоторой средой и стремится получить максимальную награду за свои действия. В этой книге разбираются ключевые аспекты этого вида обучения, его история и сферы применения. Порогом вхождения в эту книгу является лишь базовый уровень знания принципов вероятностной модели.
- Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms. В этой книге рассказывается о теории информации и о статистическом выводе. Эти темы лежат в основе таких областей современной науки, как коммуникация, теория обработки сигналов, data mining, машинное обучение, биоинформатика, криптография и многих других. Авторы удачно сочетают теоретические объяснения с практическими примерами и заданиями.
- Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning. Эта книга посвящена гауссовским процессам и вопросу обучения с учителем. В книге приведено много алгоритмов, также разбираются сферы применения ГП в машинном обучении и статистике, например, в методе опорных векторов, нейронных сетях, сплайнах и прочем.
- Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning. Эта книга пригодится студентам старших курсов с небольшим багажом знаний по линейной алгебре и матанализу. Материал в книге идёт от простого к сложному, используются графические модели.
- A Course in Machine Learning. В этой книге приведен набор вводных материалов по большинству основных аспектов машинного обучения (обучение с учителем и без учителя, вероятностное моделирование, теория обучения и т.д.).
- Machine Learning, Neural and Statistical Classification. Цель этой книги — рассказать о современных подходах к классификации. Они сравниваются по производительности и областям применения в реальных случаях. Как видно из названия, таких подходов три: статистический метод,  метод машинного обучения и метод нейронных сетей.
- Introduction To Machine Learning. В этой книге рассматриваются многие важные вопросы машинного обучения с 2006 года. Это и не учебник, и не задачник: цель книги — подготовить читателя к дальнейшему освоению этой темы.
- Real-world Machine Learning. Henri Brink, Joseph W. Richards, Mark  Fetherolf в данной книге авторы пытаются показать практическое применение машинного обучения в обыденных задачах, привести примеры их решения и собрать все важные знания для начинающего.

Comment: Если книги бесплатные, то наверняка они где-то выложены? Ссылки были бы очень полезны.

Comment: [Ссылка](https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md#machine-learning) на бесплатные книги. Там и по другим дисциплинам много.