# кросс валидация

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

код программы, кросс-валидация считается немного не так, помогите исправить

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import warnings 
from sklearn import cross_validation
warnings.simplefilter('ignore') # отключим предупреждения Anaconda
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Vika\\Downloads\\ENB2012.csv', ';')
data.head()
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split, cross_val_score
kfold = 5 #количество подвыборок для валидации
itog_val = {} #список для записи результатов кросс валидации разных алгоритмов 
X = data.values[::, 0:8]
y = data.values[::, 0:1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
print ('обучающая выборка:\n', X_train[:9])
print ('\n')
print ('тестовая выборка:\n', X_test[:7])
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
clf = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=70) 
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X_train, (y_train.ravel()*1000).astype(int), cv=kfold)
itog_val['AdaBoostClassifier'] = scores.mean()
print ('итог', itog_val)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train) 
clf.score(X_test, y_test) 
clf.predict(X_test) 
print ('AdaBoostClassifier:\n', X_test[:9])
```

ответ всегда только такой
итог `{'AdaBoostClassifier': 1.0}`

исходная выборка https://ru.files.fm/u/aempdy95

Comment: врядли вам смогут помочь не имея доступа к вашим данным...

Comment: сюда данные можно же прикрепить?

Comment: лучше выложить их на бесплатный файло-обменник и выложить здесь ссылку на файл

Comment: точно, отличная идея

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас "target" вектор который вы пытаетесь предсказать (столбец `Y1`) также присутствует в наборе данных, по которым вы делаете предсказание. Классификатор видимо заметил это однозначное соответствие и всегда делает верные предсказания по заведомо известному столбцу (первый столбец в `X` - это `Y1`).

Это как если бы мы хотели предсказать пол человека (`М`, `Ж`) по росту, весу и заранее известному полу:

```
X1   X2  X3 -> Y1
190  98  M  ->  M
160  50  Ж  ->  Ж
```

Классификатор может заметить что для предсказания достаточно использовать только последний столбец (`X3`) и, вуаля, у вас всегда предсказания со 100%-ой точностью...

Попробуйте так:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier

#import warnings
#from sklearn import cross_validation
#warnings.simplefilter('ignore') # отключим предупреждения Anaconda

data = pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\ENB2012.csv', ';')
data.head()
kfold = 5 #количество подвыборок для валидации
itog_val = {} #список для записи результатов кросс валидации разных алгоритмов
X = data.drop('Y1', axis=1).values[:, :7] # [y] столбец не должен попадать в [X]
y = data['Y1'].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
print ('обучающая выборка:\n', X_train[:9])
print ('\n')
print ('тестовая выборка:\n', X_test[:7])
clf = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=70)    
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold)
itog_val['AdaBoostClassifier'] = scores.mean()
print ('итог', itog_val)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.score(X_test, y_test)
y_test_predicted = clf.predict(X_test)
print ('AdaBoostClassifier first 9 predicted values:\n', y_test_predicted[:9])
```

Результат:

```
обучающая выборка:
 [[   2   60    3    3 7418    5    3]
 [   2   18    4    2 7374    1    1]
 [   1   12    4    0 3499    1    3]
 [   2   48    3    6 6224    1    5]
 [   4   21    3    2 1591    2    4]
 [   2   18    2    2 1924    5    2]
 [   4   24    2    9 1258    1    4]
 [   1    6    2    6  448    1    2]
 [   4   18    4    1 3850    1    4]]


тестовая выборка:
 [[   1   18    0    9 3104    1    4]
 [   2   36    2    1 9398    1    2]
 [   2    9    4    6 1136    4    5]
 [   2   24    2    0 1201    1    2]
 [   4   12    4    3 1240    5    5]
 [   4    6    1    0  783    5    3]
 [   1   16    4    0 2625    1    5]]
итог {'AdaBoostClassifier': 0.67554019014693167}
AdaBoostClassifier first 9 predicted values:
 [0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]
```

**UPDATE:**

> чтобы наглядно было видно какие "исправны"

можно создать новый DataFrame - столбец `YP` - предсказанные значения:

```
In [123]: res = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((y_test, y_test_predicted, X_test)),
     ...:                    columns=['Y1','YP'] + data.columns[1:8].tolist())
     ...:

In [124]: res
Out[124]:
     Y1  YP  X1  X2  X3  X4    X5  X6  X7
0     0   1   1  18   2   1  7511   5   5
1     1   0   1  42   4   5  3394   1   1
2     1   1   4  42   4   2  4041   3   3
3     0   1   1  12   2   3   709   1   5
4     0   1   4  24   2   9  4591   4   3
5     0   0   1  20   4   0  2235   1   3
6     1   1   1  24   4   3  1231   4   5
7     0   1   1  12   2   1  3386   1   5
8     1   1   4  24   2   3  1278   1   5
9     0   0   1  18   2   3  1882   1   3
..   ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..   ...  ..  ..
102   1   1   1  21   2   2  3599   1   4
103   1   1   4  18   4   3  2238   1   3
104   0   1   1  60   2   9  7297   1   5
105   0   0   2  12   2   2   951   2   2
106   1   0   4  10   2   6   727   3   5
107   0   0   2  12   2   3  1534   1   2
108   1   0   2  26   2   1  7966   1   2
109   1   1   4  18   2   3  1126   5   2
110   1   0   2  24   2   0  1201   1   2
111   1   1   4   6   2   3   518   1   3

[112 rows x 9 columns]
```

**UPDATE2:**

чтобы увидеть все строки - можно сохранить `res` в Excel файл:

```
res.to_excel(r'/path/to/test_data_set_and_prediction.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: спасибо Вам) но я руководитель говорил, что столбцы у обязательно должны быть в обучающей и тестовой,чтобы наглядно было видно какие исправны

Comment: столбец 'YP', в нем какие данные ?

Comment: @user280357, " столбец YP - предсказанные значения"

Comment: я примерное похожее пробовала сдать без столбцов у, ,он сказаал, что это не то и ему надо наглядность. после того как все будет выведено нужно столбец  у из тестовой выборки и столбец у из выборки с помощью классификатора сравнить и посчитать процент несовпадений

Comment: поэтому эти столбики ему надо видеть и чтоб мог примерно навскидку проверить насколько правильно считается

Comment: @user280357, зачем навскидку? - `(res['Y1'] != res['YP']).mean()`

Comment: а кросс валидация в 67, это нормально?

Comment: @user280357, это "вопрос на миллион" :-D Спросите у руководителя

Comment: потому что он не умеет кодить и знает только теорию и поэтому просто смотрит ответы и меняет размеры выборок

Comment: хаха, а можете объяснить почему в тестовой и обучающей выборках не должен находиться столбец у? я понять хочу

Comment: я поняла) вы гений)

Comment: у меня вопрос не совсем по теме с чего начинать, я очень хочу научиться кодить и не знаю с чего начать, так как книг и видосов много?

Comment: это вопрос про конкретный ЯП или вообще?

Comment: забыла, нужно добавить ввод с клавиатуры для кросс валидации, знаю что с помощью input это делается, думаю для начала мне бы логику самого питона разобрать. книги или видео уроки по питону

Comment: [По поводу Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420125/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-python). [По поводу машинного обучения.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/683632/211923) На счет машинного обучения - я сам только недавно начал изучать и сказать с чего лучше начать не могу. Лично мне очень понравился [бесплатный начальный курс по Machine Learning от Andrew Ng](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning).

Comment: ок, у Вас очень круто выходит)