# Как научиться роботехнике?

Tags: робототехника

Хочу научиться робототехнике: уметь программировать платы, делать более-менее роботов. Посоветуйте какие-то книги или курсы. Очень интересна эта тема, раньше только сайты делал и совсем не понимаю с чего начинать обучение.

Если что-то сказал неправильно, извините, некомпетентен в этой области.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474415/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678970/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю нужно начать с практики, т.е. купить простейший набор для сборки робота, допустим - робота-манипулятора, по ходу будет ясно идет или не идет, почувствуйте живьем. т.к. любой процесс автоматизации требует много терпения и зачастую не все сразу будет работать, обычно из-за невнимательности. Так что дерзайте. Данный путь быстрее, а потом и литературу для расширения кругозора в данной теме.

P.S. Затем работа с ШД - шаговые двигатели и далее более серьезная техника, допустим манипулятор - https://github.com/BCN3D/BCN3D-Moveo - проект, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xY8AwDMe--4 - видео теста BCN3D-Moveo.

Answer (score 2):

Покупаем самый простейший Arduino. Кучу модулей для ваших желаний. Далее пытаемся изучить основные принципы программирования микроконтроллеров на простейших примерах из сообщества Arduino.

Если вас это затянет и вы поймёте, что можете большее, то "Добро пожаловать в мир проектирования собственных плат и программирование микроконтроллеров". Но до такого мало кто доходит. Обычно всё заканчивается безделушками для дома/семьи или Ютуб канала.

То, как вы задали вопрос, выглядит слишком обширно. Нужно знать как электронную часть, так и программную. Это гораздо сложнее чем писать сайты в понимании "обывателя".