# Как использовать линейную регрессию при обучении нейронной сети

Tags: нейронные-сети

Прошу помощи!Никак не могу понять,как использовать линейную регрессию в обучении нейронной сети.
Я буду использовать материал из книги - Robert Callan, Essence of Neural Networks.

**Часть 1 :**

Есть у нас x и y на графике(точки).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для того,чтобы предсказать нам y по тем результатам,которые у нас есть,нам нужно построить прямую - y = mx + c.
То есть,эта прямая,при проведении которой расстояние между точками и прямой будет наименьшим - т.е,ошибка предсказаний меньше.

> y = mx + c , где m - наклон , с - сдвиг.

Для того,чтобы найти m и c использую следующие формулы -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нашел такое уравнение прямой,что при подстановке любого x я буду получать почти реальное y т.е - коэффициенты m и c.
Допустим,получилась такая прямая -

> y = 3.25x - 0.25

А теперь главные вопросы :

> Что я могу получить от этого уравнения,т.е - где веса?
>
> Каким образом мы должны заполнять график в начале?

Что за мы берем за x - все возможные входные данные на input layer?
А что за y - желаемый результат при таком входящем input ?

Было бы очень полезным , если бы привели пример обучения этим методом операции AND с input layer - x1 , x2 и Output layer - y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы извините, но у вас получилась каша.  Думаю, потому что и у многих - попыткой заняться нейронными сетями без понимания фундаментальных основ, на которых строиться Машинное Обучение, только лишь частным случаем которых есть Нейросети.

Теперь по вопросам.
У вас есть задача регрессии. Ее можно решить разными способами. Один из них вы сами уже привели - те формулы, которые вы вставили в ответ и есть решение поставленной задачи. Без всяких нейросетей. Ваши "веса" - это коэффициенты с и m. Никакого "графика (!) заполнять в начале (!!)" не надо. Вы построили  по имеющимся точкам модель в виде уравнения. Теперь вы можете подставить в полученную формулу любое, ранее неизвестное значение Х и получить для него "предсказанное" значение зависимой переменной Y. Ну, например, X=2. Тогда Y=6.25. Возможно реальное значение Y для этого Х есть несколько другим, но в рамках выбранного класса моделей ваша дает значение Y=6.25.
Задача решена.

Но! Для получения указанных формул вычислений коэффициентов вначале задается мера оценки ошибки модели, в классическом случае - как сумму квадратов разницы  между известными значениями Y и предсказанными моделью значениями в тех-же точках Х.  Потом строиться  переопределенная системе уравнений, которая решается относительно коэффициентов с и m. Именно за счет выбора указанной меры оказывается, что эта система имеет аналитическое решение, которое вы и используете в виде готовых формул.

Однако если вы пожелаете использовать другую меру ошибки модели или если у вас точки Х будут заданы в многомерном пространстве, то так просто решение уже не найти. В этих случаях единственное, что остается - использовать численные методы решения систем уравнений, как правило - оптимизационный метод градиентного спуска. Нейронная сеть есть не более, чем "маркетинговая обертка" для методов этого класса. И вот в результате использования этого подхода вы получаете свою регрессионную модель уже  в виде наборов коэффициентов, связывающих неким замысловатым способом ваши многомерные Х и одномерную Y.

Можно, конечно и в вашем случае попытаться использовать нейросеть, но это примерно то-же, что стрелять даже не из пушки, а из ракеты - по воробью. Более развернутое описание вы можете найти, например, вот тут

https://habr.com/post/307004/

Поэтому, отвечая на ваш вопрос, не линейную регрессию используют при построении нейронной сети, а с помощью нейронной сети строят (а затем - используют) регрессионные (или классификационные, или кластеризационные и т.д.) модели.

Вот как-то примерно так.

Comment: Спасибо просто огромнейшее.Буду дальше читать книги и пытаться добиться цели - сделать нейронку,которая будет распознавать нарисованные мною цифры от 0 до 10.А вы можете пожалуйста посоветовать какие-то простые книги для ввода в эту тему?

Comment: Я могу посоветовать начать не с распознавания цифр, а с основ. И постепенно усложняя, естественным образом "дорасти" до вашей задачи. Попытайтесь посмотреть вот тут, може найдете такие, которые вам будет проще освоить: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678970/Книги-и-учебные-ресурсы-по-машинному-обучению или вот тут http://ai-news.ru/2018/10/podborka_resursov_po_mashinnomu_obucheniu.html

Comment: Пожалуйста,посоветуйте с основ.В принципе,я уже сделал нейронную сеть для AND,OR,XOR.Обучал с помощью правила Видроу-Хоффа.

Comment: Все,я понял все мои недопонимания.Ну,большую часть так точно!Относительно моего вопроса.Получается,методом наименьших квадратов мы находим приблизительное уравнение.Если мы посчитаем суму ошибок,то получится некое число.В идеале,нам нужно сделать эту суму максимально малой.В дело может вступить нейронка,которая будет принимать на вход 2 числа,x1 - будет брать c ,которая всегда будет на вход приходить 1.Потом x2 - это наши аргументы x.Активационная функция - линейная.Что пришло,то и ушло.Шаблоном будет точки,которые предлагаются нам в условии.И дальше,можно обучать с помощью дельта правила.

Comment: в идеале мы должны в итоге найти более точную прямую.А,веса будут c и m.

Comment: Поняли, да не совсем точно. Если в качестве меры ошибки использовать  ту же самую сумму квадратов отклонений, то никогда вы не получите нейронной решение более точное, чем аналитически. Ну а про "на вход  с и еще что-то, активация линейна" - это вообще что-то феерически отдаленное от реальности. Все-таки, начните с азов.