# Изучение нейросетей

Tags: нейронные-сети

Хочу изучить нейросети, но столкнулся с проблемой, что не хватает знаний в области математики. Подскажите пожалуйста какие темы необходимо изучить? Будет круто если скинете ссылку на курс.

Comment: начните с линейной алгебры...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первое, чему должен научиться тот, кто желает стать специалистом по машинному обучению, нейронным сетям и анализу данных -  это научиться самостоятельно искать и находить ответы, а не ждать, что кто-то их найдет по вашему желанию.

Но будем считать, что вас забанили в Гуугл, поэтому выдать элементарный запрос и найти кучу ответов вы по каким-то причинам не в состоянии. Поэтому вот вам ссылочки из первого десятка, изучайте:

https://habr.com/ru/company/plarium/blog/442772/

http://ai-news.ru/2018/12/vazhnye_aspekty_matematiki_v_nauke_o_dannyh_chto_i_pochemu.html

https://habr.com/ru/post/432670/

[Книги и учебные ресурсы по машинному обучению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678970/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E)

Удачи в освоении!