# Создание искусственного интелекта

Tags: python, искусственный-интеллект

Всем добрый день!

Очень заинтересовался созданием искусственного интеллекта, но не могу найти, с чего начать. Язык не имеет значения, но желательно питон.

То, как я его представляю: допустим функция, которая принимает некоторый массив данных, возвращает, и получает либо результат true/false, либо % успеха, либо ожидаемый результат. От того и учится.

Сейчас есть много библиотек, которые заточены под определенные функции, например разбор картинки. Мне же нужно максимум возможностей, чтобы попробовать реализовать самые разные алгоритмы, к примеру:

1: входной массив: клетки вокруг змейки в мини-игре

2: математические вычисления, к примеру обычное квадратное уравнение

3: анализ какого-то графика, прогнозирование следующего значения

Я понимаю, что тут много работы, и есть готовые библиотеки для каждого решения, хочу начать именно с самых азов, реализовать все вручную

Буду благодарен за любую ссылку/видео/инструкцию

Comment: [Открытый курс OpenDataScience по машинному обучению](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVlY_7IJCMJdgcCtQfzj5j8OVB_Y0GJCl)

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по машинному обучению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678970/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала советую Вам полностью разобраться во всех этих терминах и не путаться. То, что вы описываете сложно назвать "искусственным интеллектом". Это скорее нейронная сеть.

Так же при условии, что вы предполагаете начать с самого начала (не используя готовых решений и т.д) Вам следует хорошо владеть высшей математикой (или хотя бы на базовом уровне, для понимания).

**Ресурсы для введения:**

1. https://habr.com/ru/post/312450/
2. Книга - Make Your Own Neural Network
3. Книга - A Brief Introduction to Neural Networks
4. Книга Тарик Рашид - Создаем нейронную сеть
5. Видеоматериал - https://youtu.be/aircAruvnKk (С переводом - https://youtu.be/RJCIYBAAiEI)

Comment: Спасибо! Да, я имел ввиду нейронные сети)