# Машинное обучение. Обучение с нуля

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, kaggle

Только начинаю изучать библиотеки для машинного обучения, потихоньку знакомлюсь с kaggle.

Хотелось бы чтобы вы поделились ресурсами для изучения данной области. Да, я гуглил, много информации прочитал, но хотелось бы услышать что-то от опытных специалистов.

Уровень, к которому хотелось бы подготовиться - устроиться на работу хотя бы junior'ом.

Comment: [Ресурсы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678970/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для общего понимания и кругозора можно пройти образовательные курсы на той же Курсере. Хотя бы получите общее представление о спектре задач машинного обучения и какими методами эти задачи решаются. Ну а дальше - разбираться самому, много гуглить, брать интересную задачу и пробовать ее решить.

Учтите, что задачи на kaggle это лишь верхушка айсберга. Львиная доля работы специалиста - это сбор данных, анализ того какие данные, как и где собирать. На kaggle вам дают уже все готовое.

Answer (score 1):

Вы действительно на полном серьезе считаете что тут, в несколько строк или абзацев "опытные специалисты" вам расскажут больше, чем написано в горах книг и сотнях сайтов,  показано в десятках видеокурсах посвященных теме машинного обучения?

Мой вам совет - хотите изучать ML - не ищите причин этого НЕ делать, не теряйте времени зря. А просто начинайте учить. А вот как что-то станет непонятным,, какие-то темы особо заинтересуют - задавайте  конкретные вопросы.

Ну и про "уровень юниора". Это в первую очередь - освоить Google, научиться  самостоятельно искать и отбирать информацию, работать с ней, а не бежать по каждому элементарному вопросу на SO. Вот с этого и начните.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал сделать самому маленькую полносвязную сеть для разделения Xor(на Numpy можно).Сложновато.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ.