# Как учить линейную алгебру для ИИ семикласснику?

Tags: математика, машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект

Вообщем, мне 13 лет и я учусь в 7 классе. После обучение яп Python, я хочу начать изучение ИИ и машинного обучения. Какую литературу или какой ресурс вы мне посоветуете для изучение линейной алгебры(школьный курс математики,
вплоть до 7 класса, я знаю хорошо)

Comment: Попробуйте [курсы на stepik](https://stepik.org/catalog?q=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0&tag=22760)

Comment: Может быть, учебники алгебры за 10-11 класс и учебник линейной алгебры для технических вузов? Матрицы — штука довольно простая, только абстрактная немного.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, для машинного обучения и ИИ кроме матриц понадобятся частные производные. Я не знаю школьную программу по математике в стране автора топика, но подозреваю, что в 7м классе этого не преподают  ;)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по машинному обучению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678970/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)