# Python. Нейронные сети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Я хочу научиться писать нейронные сети на Python языке. С помощью какой библиотеки в Python лучше реализовывать нейронные сети? С чего начинать в целом. Есть ли у кого-нибудь примеры простых нейронных сетей?

Comment: Для того чтобы что-то запрограммировать при помощи любой библиотеки сначала надо понять что именно вы кодируете! Т.е. сначала надо понять общие принципы работы машинного обучения и нейронных сетей. Если вы понимаете как все работает то можете выбирать: `pytorch`, `keras`, `tensorflow`. Думаю, для начала вам хватит... Если такого понимания нет, тогда стоит начать с [азов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678970)

Comment: С математикой проблем нет.

Comment: Какую из перечисленных вами библиотек проще использовать ?

Comment: встречный вопрос: а какие у вас цели? ;) Начинать, наверное, легче всего с `keras`...

Comment: https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python

Comment: Цели пока нет :) Я хочу прощупать почву в данной области

Comment: Что вы можете сказать о Scikit-learn библиотеке?

Comment: sklearn- активно используется для препроцессинга и постпроцессинга. В нем конечно есть `Multi-layer Perceptron`, но в наше время им пользуются, пожалуй, только в академических целях

Comment: Спасибо за советы :)

Comment: Насколько сложно изучать машинное обучение ?

Comment: Очень сложно. Особенно тем, кто еще не научился самостоятельно Гууглить ответы  даже на простейшие до примитивности вопросы.