# Хочу заниматься разработкой искусственного интеллекта, чему учиться?

Tags: искусственный-интеллект

Я хочу заниматься разработкой искусственного интеллекта (есть личные интересы) и, по возможности, совместить это с работой, те устроиться на работу где я смогу этим заниматься. Можете ли вы порекомендовать какое-то обучение для этого? И, если знаете, то какое, в перспективе трудоустройство?

Comment: "чему учиться" - математике для начала, чтобы вот так не получилось - https://habrastorage.org/getpro/habr/comment_images/248/3a7/ec6/2483a7ec64614422335725a6389c652e.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендация №1.

Научится самостоятельно (!!!) искать ответы хотя-бы на элементарные вопросы. Вы же не думаете, что вы первый, у кого возник такой вопрос. Начать можете с Гуугл:

```
https://www.mltut.com/best-way-to-learn-data-science-for-complete-beginners/
https://habr.com/ru/company/plarium/blog/505458/
https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-in-machine-learning-data-science-a-guide-for-social-scientists-d4cdd6332eb0
https://www.cyberforum.ru/ai/thread2010374.html#post10584290
https://ai-news.ru/2018/10/podborka_resursov_po_mashinnomu_obucheniu.html
https://www.kaggle.com/getting-started/73164#latest-663707
https://tproger.ru/curriculum/data-scientist-curriculum/
https://habr.com/ru/post/432670/
```

Если по Гуугл трудно, то хотя-бы по этому форуму:

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678970/Книги-и-учебные-ресурсы-по-машинному-обучению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678970/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E)

Рекомендация №2.

*Можете ли вы порекомендовать какое-то обучение для этого?* - Да, можем. Поступаете в универ, на специальности которые в  называются "Data Science", "Системный анализ", "Прикладная математика", просто "Математика" или близкими к этому. Желательно - в хороший вуз. После окончания получаете phD.

Рекомендация №3.

*какое, в перспективе трудоустройство?* Если будете прилежно учиться и действительно стремиться получить знания, то степень даст вам преимущество перед теми толпами желающих освоить "самую сексуальную профессию 21-века" и загребать деньги лопатой, но которые считают, что выучив вызов трех методов и освоив полтора фреймворка уже стали "Датасайентистами".

Answer (score 1):

Стремление к таким сложным вещам, как ИИ - очень похвально.
Сначала рекомендую хорошенько изучить дискретную математику, да и не только её, чтобы развить умение размышлять логически. Без этого не удастся написать ни ИИ, ни калькулятор. Далее советую взяться за алгоритмы.
Хорошенько освоив эти две области - язык программирования в зубы, и читать книги.
Языков для ИИ очень много, но лично от себя советую Python, Rust или C#.
Выбрав язык, хорошенько покопайтесь в нем.А затем, поняв язык, начинайте читать книги о разработке ИИ на выбранном языке.
Тут сколько людей - столько мнений, но я описал путь, который действительно даст знания, а не пустые надежды.
В остальном удачи, не бросай начатое, и будь уверен - у тебя все получится.

Answer (score 1):

AI стал слишком обширной областью в наше время, поэтому ваш вопрос слишком общий.
Вам надо определиться хотя бы какой раздел AI вас интересует:

- Робототехника (автопилот и т.д.)
- Работа с изображениями
- Работа со звуком
- Работа с текстами
- Работа с данными
- Работа с временными рядами
- Голосовые помощники
- ...

В принципе, там везде нужно будет хотя бы базовое знание статистики, Python и основных библиотек, математическую подготовку. Но конкретные знания и умения очень сильно различаются в зависимости от конкретной области применения.

Для обучения всё есть в интернете - бесплатные и платные курсы на различных платформах, обучающие видео на ютьюбе, примеры программного кода, статьи, да что угодно. Главное понять - куда вы хотите двигаться и начать это всё изучать и применять хоть понемногу.