# Tensorflow. Документация и что учить прежде

Tags: python-3.x, машинное-обучение, tensorflow, документация

Уважаемые программисты. Я новичок в python, вроде как изучил основы, и очень хочу научить ПК самому играть в игры. Хочу использовать q обучение через модуль tensorflow. Но не нашел адекватной документации на русском(только как примеры решать). Подксажите пожалуйста ссылочку на сайт, и что выучить прежде чтобы что-то понимать. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: [DataCamp](https://learn.datacamp.com/) Неплох вплане освоения основных библиотек. Есть еще Kaggle.com - мастодонт ML. Но начинать стоит конечно с полного освоения языка. Ведь программное взаимодействие с игрой - уже нетривиальная задача

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по машинному обучению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678970/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 0):

`Нишант Шакла: Машинное обучение и TensorFlow`

Хорошая книга, в которой с нуля объясняются разные подходы к машинному обучению и много практики. После её прочтения у тебя должно получиться создавать свои нейронные сети на tf.