# План чтения по искусственному интеллекту, Data Science, Data Mining, Big Data, нейросетям

Tags: нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект, big-data

Предложите, пожалуйста, план чтения с нуля и до профи в этих областях. На сайтах очень размытые определения, а плавать в этих областях не хочется. Желательно не опираться на конкретную технологию или язык программирования. Есть интуитивное понимание, что это переименованная математика времён СССР, но не более того. Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по машинному обучению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678970/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тема слишком обширная.

- Начните с определений в Википедии. Да, будет непонятно, но главное начать. Прочитайте определения всех этих терминов.
- Посмотрите видео в ютьюбе по тем же словам какие-то для начинающих. Общее представление получите таким образом.
- Далее выберите конкретную тему, которой вы хотите заниматься. Это зависит от ваших предпочтений и от вашей цели

  - Хотите устроиться на работу? Смотрите, что требуется в вакансиях
  - Хотите заниматься генерацией картинок, анализом текстов, предсказанием курса акций, подсчётом пингвинов на спутниковом снимке, предсказанием складских запасов в супермаркете... - копайте уже соответственную тему, всё знать невозможно, тем более сразу

Это очень обширная и очень сложная тема, на её полное изучение может вся жизнь уйти. Статистика и теория вероятностей времён СССР очень даже может помочь, но это всего лишь теоретическая база, над которой наработана очень большая надстройка за последние годы. Да и сама теоретическая база была сильно расширена.

Сейчас есть много и текстов в интернете и обучающих видео любой степени погружения на ютьюбе и курсы на любой вкус. План обучения конкретно под вас составить можете только вы сами. Слишком много всего, вы должны сами понять свои интересы и свои слабые места. И выбирать материалы и курсы соответственно.