# Ресурсы для изучения XAF

Tags: c#, devexpress

Ищу ресурсы для изучения фреймворка XAF . Что можете посоветовать помимо документации на официальном сайте ? Гугл ничего ценного не выдал. Есть ли какие нибудь простые опен-сорс проекты , чтобы изучить ?

Comment: Из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать: ... Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию. Для списков литературы выделены особые поддерживаемые сообществом вопросы. Вместо того, чтобы задавать новый вопрос, найдите уже существующий в [вопросе-указателе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/208074). Также список литературы и других ресурсов часто можно найти в описаниях меток по соответствующим темам.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле на официальном сайте DevExpress, как мне кажется, есть всё для удобного изучения XAF. Там и последовательные статьи и примеры кода.
Вот 3 ссылки которые должны ответить на базовые вопросы:

[eXpressApp Framework](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument112670)

[Fundamentals](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument115141)

[Getting Started](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument113577)

Мой ответ: Нет. Нет более емких и подробных ресурсов на тему XAF кроме документации DevExpress.

Но может быть вам чем-нибудь поможет вот [этот](http://xaf-lessons.tumblr.com/) ресурс.