# Книги и учебные ресурсы по Kotlin

Tags: книги, kotlin, kotlin-faq

Собираем подборку качественной литературы по **Kotlin**.

Дописывайте, если есть что добавить в общий ответ.

Формат для печатных изданий:

> Название, Авторы. Год ISBN.

Приветствуется указание на русский перевод в формате:

> Название, Авторы. Издательство, Год, ISBN.

Электронные ресурсы оформляются в виде ссылок.

---

> Данный перечень входит в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных
>   ресурсов по программированию.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### Общие

- Kotlin in Action, Dmitry Jemerov and Svetlana Isakova. February 2017 ISBN 9781617293290

  Русский перевод: Kotlin в действии, Жемеров Д. Б., Исакова С. С., ДМК-Пресс, 2018 г. ISBN 9781617293290.
- Fundamental Kotlin, Miloš Vasić. 2017 ISBN: 9788692030703
- Язык программирования Kotlin, Сергей Пименов. 2017 ISBN: 9786177453283
- Reactive Programming in Kotlin: Design and build non-blocking, asynchronous Kotlin applications with RXKotlin, Reactor-Kotlin, Android, and Spring, Rivu Chakraborty. 2017 ISBN: 9781788473026
- Kotlin Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide, Josh Skeen, David Greenhalgh. 2018 ISBN: 9780135161630
- The Joy of Kotlin, Pierre-Yves Saumont. 2018 ISBN: 9781617295362

  Русский перевод: Волшебство Kotlin, Саймон Пьер-Ив, Manning Publications, 2019 г. ISBN 9785970608012.
- Head First Kotlin A Brain-Friendly Guide, David Griffiths, Dawn Griffiths, Прогресс книга. 2019 ISBN: 9781491996690

  Русский перевод: Head First Kotlin, Гриффитс Д., Manning Publications, 2019 г. ISBN 9785446113354.
- Programmer's Guide To Kotlin, Mike James. 2017 ISBN: 9781871962536
- The Joy of Kotlin, Pierre-Yves Saumont. 2019 ISBN: 9781617295362
- Hands-on Design Patterns with Kotlin, Alexey Soshin. 2018 ISBN: 9781788998017
- Learning Concurrency in Kotlin, Miguel Angel Castiblanco Torres. 2018 ISBN: 9781788627160
- Kotlin Programming Cookbook, Aanand Shekhar Roy, Rashi Karanpuria. 2018 ISBN: 9781788472142
- Atomic Kotlin, Bruce Eckel, Svetlana Isakova. 2021 ISBN: 9780981872551
- Programming Kotlin, Venkat Subramaniam. 2019 ISBN: 9781680506358
- Список книг на [официальном сайте](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/books.html)

### Web Development

- Modern Web Development with Kotlin, Denis Kalinin. 2017
- Programming Kotlin, Stephen Samuel, Stefan Bocutiu. 2017 ISBN: 9781787126367
- Hands-On Microservices with Kotlin, Juan Antonio Medina Iglesias. 2018 ISBN: 9781788471459
- Building Applications with Spring 5 and Kotlin,  Miloš Vasić. 2018 ISBN: 9781788394802
- Kotlin for Enterprise Applications using Java EE, Raghavendra Rao K. 2018 ISBN: 9781788997270

### Android

- Kotlin for Android Developers, Antonio Leiva. 2017
- Android Development with Kotlin, Marcin Moskala, Igor Wojda. 2017 ISBN: 9781787123687
- Mastering Android Development with Kotlin, Miloš Vasić. 2017 ISBN: 9781788473699
- Kotlin Apprentice, raywenderlich.com Team, Irina Galata, Joe Howard, Dick Lucas, Ellen Shapiro. 2018 ISBN: 9781942878506
- Learning Kotlin by building Android Applications: Explore the fundamentals of Kotlin while building real-world Android applications, Eunice Adutwumwaa Obugyei, Natarajan Raman. 2018 ISBN: 9781788474641
- Android Programming with Kotlin for Beginners: Build Android apps starting from zero programming experience with the new Kotlin programming language, John Horton. 2019
- Kickstart Modern Android Development with Jetpack and Kotlin: Enhance your applications by integrating Jetpack and applying modern app architectural concepts, Catalin Ghita. 2022
- Android UI Development with Jetpack Compose,Thomas Künneth. 2022

### Онлайн-ресурсы

- [Официальная документация](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-docs.pdf)
- [Документация на русском](http://kotlinlang.ru/)
- [Официальный сайт Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/)
- [Репозиторий Github с исходным кодом](https://github.com/jetbrains/kotlin)
- [Онлайн редактор](https://try.kotlinlang.org)
- [Awesome Kotlin](https://github.com/KotlinBy/awesome-kotlin)
- [From Java to Kotlin](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/from-java-to-kotlin)
- [Руководство по корутинам](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-guide.html)
- [Kotlin® Notes for Professionals book](https://books.goalkicker.com/KotlinBook/)
- [Start Android](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/kotlin.html) - уроки по Android на Kotlin
- [Kotlin Multiplatform](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform.html) - Разработка под разные платформы на Kotlin
- [KEEP](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP) - Предложения по развитию языка
- [Youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT) - Баг-трекер, доска задач языка Kotlin

### Библиотеки и фреймворки

- [Kotlinx Coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines) - официальная библиотека для кроссплатформенной разработки корутин
- [Kotlinx Serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) - официальная библиотека сериализации
- [Kotlinx AtomicFu](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.atomicfu) - официальная библиотека для кроссплатформенной работы с атомарными операциями
- [Ktor](https://ktor.io/) - фреймворк для построения асинхронных HTTP клиентов и серверов
- [TornadoFX](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx) - JavaFX фреймворк для Kotlin

## Онлайн курсы

- [JetBrains: Изучение Kotlin на примерах](https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/overview)
- [JetBrains: Kotlin Koans](https://play.kotlinlang.org/koans/overview)
- [Stepik: Введение в Kotlin JVM](https://stepik.org/course/5448/)
- [Stepik: Разработка Android-приложений на Kotlin](https://stepik.org/course/4792)
- [Stepik: Kotlin](https://stepik.org/course/2852) *(англ.)* - курс от JetBrains на основе [Kotlin Koans](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/koans.html)
- [Hyperskill](https://hyperskill.org) *(англ.)* - сайт с заданиями и учебными проектами на нескольких языках программирования, в том числе на Kotlin.