# Как такое реализовать на Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

Не могу понять, еще изучаю, в интернете найти не могу, подскажите как правильно называть данное выражение и как его написать на kotlin

```
 pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
```

Если что еще полный цикл приложу

```
int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    int offset = y * width;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
    }
}
```

Буду очень благодарен, если подскажите еще, где можно подучить подобное)

Comment: Судя по всему программа читает Bitmap  и на его основе создает массив boolean переменных.

Comment: По поводу изучения - посмотрите список учебных ресурсов здесь: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Kotlin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732964/Книги-и-учебные-ресурсы-по-kotlin) и [курсы по Kotlin на Stepik.org](https://stepik.org/catalog?q=kotlin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если просто попробовать вставить ваш код в Intellij IDEA в kotlin файл, сразу будет предложено сконвертировать из Java в Kotlin (тестировалось на Intellij IDEA 2019.3 Community).

Результат такой:

```
val pixels = IntArray(width * height)
for (y in 0 until height) {
    val offset: Int = y * width
    for (x in 0 until width) {
        pixels[offset + x] = if (result.get(x, y)) BLACK else WHITE
    }
}
```

На мой взгляд, все сконвертировалось адекватно. Единственно, в строке

```
val offset: Int = y * width
```

указание типа не обязательно, можно записать просто как

```
val offset = y * width
```