# Уроки по классу Pattern в java/kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

Всем привет! Кто-нибудь знает, где можно детально изучить всю работу с классом Pattern?
Где бы не искал, находил лишь неполный материал:\

Comment: в документации по классу?

Comment: Что-то попроще, содержащее примеры с регулярными выражениями.

Comment: вы же понимаете, что определение "полный\не полный материал" и "сложный\не сложный материал" находится только у вас в голове и тут вы по сути предлагаете людям гадать, что вам подойдет, а что не подойдет? Вот книги по [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416635/179763) и [kotlin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/732965/179763) - вперед и с песней, как говорится.

Comment: По сути я попросил **людей** подсказать мне источник с уроками по данному классу. Если вы мне не можете помочь в данном вопросе - "вперед и с песней"

Comment: все [книги и другие материалы для обучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/179763) на этом сайте собираются в конкретных ответах, я специально среди них нашел для вас разделы, что вам интересны - по java и kotlin, то есть сделал именно то, что вы просили. Так как я не знаю, что для вас подходит, я вам скинул все, что тут есть. "вперед и с песней" означает призыв вам проглядеть материал, что я вам дал. Что это означает в вашем комментарии я не понял.

Comment: Я благодарю вас за данные ссылки и, вероятно, воспринял ваш ответ "в штыки", а потому ответил несколько грубо. Если конкретнее, выражение "Вперед и с песней" в моём сообщении гласило, что если вы не можете ответить на мой вопрос - пропустите его, как поступили 10 (на данный момент) человек.

Comment: Я за 6 лет и почти 9к комментариев просто перестал тратить время на реверансы, потому я вас не виню, но поверьте - у меня нет ни капли враждебности к вам. Я вам скинул все ссылки, что знал, но, так как это явно не отвечает на ваш вопрос - я скинул их комментарием. Возможно вам кто-то скинет руководства получше, хотя в этом мало шансов, так как если то, что вы просите, гуглится легко - то вы скорее всего это уже видели. К тому же большинство ориентируется больше на документацию, чем на уроки по конкретным классам.

Comment: К сожалению, документация плохо мной понимается:( Во всяком случае это вероятнее всего решит мою проблему, спасибо!

Comment: Кстати, если у вас проблема с пониманием регулярных выражений - то это отдельный вопрос, по регуляркам есть отдельные справки \ книги \ курсы и даже онлайн инструменты.

Comment: **Была** проблема, да, но решил. Далее заинтересовала общая работа с классами Pattern&Macther ну а ресурсы, что я нашёл давали неполный багаж знаний по этому, как мне кажется, **необходимому** классу

Comment: Скорее всего то, что вы ищите - просто не существует. Разве что да, книги непосредственно по регулярным выражениям, без привязки к языку, в рамках которого они используются. В отрыве же от непосредственно регулярных выражений писать про их использование именно в Java и про какой-то отдельный класс нет особого смысла, если не давать только общие соображения, т.к. сам класс и язык Java тут вторичны.

Comment: Дело не конкретно в регулярных выражениях, об этом я выразился ранее. К тому же проблема решена)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// пользуйтесь на здоровье если поможет

```
/*МЕТАСИМВОЛЫ -поиска совпадений границ стр или текста
 * ^ -начало строки                      /*МЕТАСИМВОЛЫ -поиска символьных классов
 * $ -конец строки                               * \d -цифра
 * \b -граница слова                             * \D -НЕ цифра
 * \B -НЕ граница слова                          * "\\s" -пробел
 * \A -начало ввода                              * \S -НЕ пробел
 * \G -конец предыдущего совпадения              * \w -буква, цифра, __
 * \Z -конец ввода                               * \W -НЕ буква, НЕ цифра, НЕ__
 * \z -конец ввода                               * "." -любой символ
 */                                         

/*МЕТАСИМВОЛЫ -поиска символов редактирования текста
 * \t -[TAB]                                /*МЕТАСИМВОЛЫ -группировки символов
 * \n -new строка                           * [asd] -любой из a,s,d
 * \r -возврат каретки                      * [^asd] -любой кроме a,s,d
 * \f -переход на new страницу              * [a-zA-Z] -от а до z ignoreCase
 * \u0085 -следующая строка                 * [a-d[n-z]] обьединение a-d и n-z
 * \u2028 -разделение строк                 * [a-z&&[def]] -пересечение
 * \u2029 -разделение абзацев           * [a-z&&[^bc]] -вычитание(все кроме b,c)
 * \u00A7 -разделение параграфов
 */

/* КВАНТИФИКАТОР -обозначение кол-ва символов
 * + -совпадение 1раз или больше               
 * * -совпадение 0раз или больше    
 * ? -совпадение 1раз или отсутствует           
 * {n} -совпадение n раз                        
 * {n,} -совпадение n раз и более 
 * {n,m} -совпадение от n до m раз
 */
```

/*МЕХАНИЗМ ПОИСКА

- "A.+a" -жадный(->A->->до конца затем a<-<-)
- "A.++a" -сверхжадный (->A->->до конца)
- "A.+?a" -ленивый режим (->A->->a->A->->a->конец)
  */

Comment: Будем считать это действительным решением проблемы, спасибо!

Comment: методы много где описаны,  а табличку пришлось самому собирать))