# Как работать с эмуляторами андроида в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-c++, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Данные о приложении и системе:
Windows 7 x64; Visual Studio 2019, установлены надстройки: Разработка мобильных приложений на .net, Разработка мобильных приложений на языке C++

Всем доброго времени суток! Я решила заняться изучением мобильных приложений и попробовать написать приложение сама. Имею опыт знакомства с VS для написания приложений Windows, в связи с чем решила остановиться на этом. И вот первая проблема, которая заключается в следующем. У меня либо нет встроенного эмулятора и его надо устанавливать отдельно, либо VS его не видит. Пыталась установить эмулятор, который предлагает сайт майкрософт специально для VS (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/msft-android-emulator/?ranMID=46131&ranEAID=a1LgFw09t88&ranSiteID=a1LgFw09t88-c5oVoVMLAz3ctJSI1kCWaQ&epi=a1LgFw09t88-c5oVoVMLAz3ctJSI1kCWaQ&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2200057_aff_7806_1243925&tduid=%28ir__bl6cvc1vwwkftga6kk0sohz3xm2xr0slvtiu00tt00%29%287806%29%281243925%29%28a1LgFw09t88-c5oVoVMLAz3ctJSI1kCWaQ%29%28%29&irclickid=_bl6cvc1vwwkftga6kk0sohz3xm2xr0slvtiu00tt00); но когда попыталась это сделать, получила сообщение о том, что моя система не соответствует требованиям (для начала у меня 7ка, требует 8ку и выше). Что мне стоит скачать или как бороться с тем, что VS его не видит?

А еще буду признательна, если посоветуете хорошие статьи по мобильной разработке. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если вы серьезно решили разрабатывать под Android , то стоит скачать Android Studio и начинать изучать Java/Kotlin. Кросплатформенные решения пока еще далеки от нативных.

Comment: Для начала обновиться до свежей Windows 10. Android Studio 7 тоже уже не поддерживает.

Comment: @pavlofff Надо попробовать. А Вы можете посоветовать хороший обучающий материал по этим языкам? они мне вообще не близки. Win10, если что, в запасе имеется.

Comment: По самим языкам Java/Kotlin начать можно с книг издательства Head First. Лучшей книгой по фреймворку андроид я считаю книги Б.Филлипса "android. Программирование для професионалов", последнее издание по Kotlin, более ранние по Java. Отличает то, что это не просто учебник, а как бы мастер-класс с наставником по разработке реальных приложений.

Comment: Список литературы по Kotlin - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/732965/177345 , список по Java - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416635/177345 . Все эти Swing, Spring и прочее не понадобится в андроид, только Core Java

Comment: Спасибо! Буду изучать.