# Выбор варианта изучения языка

Tags: python, c

Начал изучать Си. Задумался над двумя разными подходами к изучению.

А. Писать код по книжному без понимания что он делает.
Б. Писать код по своему и в дальнейшем модифицировать его до книжного по мере изучения языка.

Например: на данный момент я не умею работать с файлами (*.CSV в частности).
По вар.А у меня уйдет уйма времени пока я разберусь как работают файловые функции.
По вар.Б я сохраню часть файла в строке вручную и далее буду работать с этой частью, реализуя другие функции доступные моему пониманию)

Или другой пример: Я не изучил циклы, но уже изучил операции goto и if
Вар.А - буду учить циклы попутно при написании программы
Вар.Б - реализую цикл используя if-goto

Хотелось бы услышать советы по стратегии обучения.

Comment: Читайте книжки и решайте практические задачи. Видео в интернете обычно отвратительны, я ещё не видел ни одного хорошего.

Comment: @VladD, https://youtu.be/Ng3awE4dNSI И прочее оттуда (скоро появятся видео с ноябрьского YAPC::Russia, и дело вовсе не в перле...)

Comment: @PinkTux: Мне сложно оценить качество, я не знаю Perl. Но это, как мне кажется, не обучающее видео. По нему ни основ языка, ни тем более тонкостей не выучишь. Так что как обучающее видео этот пример не катит.

Comment: По программированию есть как минимум два типа книг: 1) цель - дать максимально быстро базу языка, примеры: "язык X за 24 часа", "карманный справочник по языку X". Эти книги дают необходимый минимум "по верхам", объем небольшой, прочесть можно за пару-тройку вечеров. 2) цель - полностью описать все нюансы языка, применяемые фреймворки и проч. Объемы таких книг велики, их используют как справочники, прочитать от корки до корки мало у кого получается :) Начинать следует с 1), затем нужно сразу переходить к собственным проектам, почитывая тип 2).

Comment: @Bulson: И списки этих самых книг у нас есть на сайте :)

Comment: @VladD, да, важное замечание, только вот ссылку я запамятовал.

Comment: @Bulson: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/10105

Comment: @VladD вот спасибо.

Comment: @Bulson: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD, зато мотивирующее, и объясняющие пути в общем и целом (ну, как мне кажется). Особенно под конец интервью. А на исходный вопрос я не знаю ответа... Странный он, IMHO, очень странный.

Comment: @PinkTux: Видео (исходя из той части, которую я успел посмотреть) хорошее. Но оно просто не учебное.

Comment: @VladD (отвлечённо) дождитесь записи  его доклада про то, как на Perl войти в топ Highload Cup. Но не про Perl. Там и про С, и про плюсы, и про поиски узких мест, и про оптимизацию ко времени/по делу, etc. Слушал с разинутым ртом, это был лучший доклад. В минут 40 уложил как работает мозг программиста над узкой задачей в течении 2 недель :) И к чему в идеале нужно стремиться. То есть с этой точки зрения - очень даже обучающая. Есть "сквозная" запись конференции (>8 часов), но копаться там и проматывать - не комфортно, да и скукотищи там много (впрочем, как и в любой работе программиста).

Answer (score 5):

Алгоритм очень простой.

Во-первых, нужно прочитать книгу начального уровня. Чтобы знать, что есть в языке, и вместо массивов не использовать переменные, а вместо словарей — eval.
Если в книге есть примеры, стоит их проштудировать.

Затем, имеет смысл попробовать свой простой проект. Он будет ужасен, но это нормально. Если у вас есть опытные в данном языке знакомые, попросите их посмотреть код, и попытайтесь понять их замечания.

Затем, нужно читать более продвинутые книги, и одновременно кодировать более продвинутые проекты. Повторять до конца карьеры.

Конец алгоритма.

---

Не старайтесь сэкономить время, заменив книги видеокурсами. Качество у них обычно отвратительное. Подумайте, хотите ли вы кататься на машине, разработчики которой *экономили время* на изучение инженерного дела.

Comment: Посмею немного поправить. Книги имеют смысл в основном для понимания базы. Уже при реальной работе надо учиться пользоваться документацией и не ждать, что какой-то автор все вам разжует и покажет

Comment: @СашаБоричевский: Ну в общем-то вы правы. Но мне кажется, что если в какой-то момент времени достаточно одной лишь документации, то либо вы достигли уровня гуру, либо пришло время ставить перед собой более сложные задачи.

Comment: если честно - не считаю себя гуру, и да, могу иногда ерунду написать, по моим ответам на сайте скорее всего это видно) Однако тупо за работой нет времени выискивать хорошую книжку и читать, так что все проблемы решаются по мере поступления и только через документацию, ну и изредка здесь поискать можно

Answer (score 3):

Научиться можно только читая книжки и параллельно решая сотни маленьких задач.

Чем больше языков вы таким образом освоите, тем проще  будет понимать (и быстрее учить) каждый следующий.

Возможно через некоторое время вам захочется придумать и реализовать свой язык, который будет включать все лучшее из изученных. И вот тут вы начнете по настоящему постигать те языки, про которые раньше читали и писали на них эти сотни примеров.

Вероятно в этот момент вас всерьез заинтересует, а как именно устроены компьютерное железо, операционные системы, интернет и т.д.

Почитав про это и пощупав все своими руками (скорее всего у этому моменту вы уже будете работать в какой-нибудь программно-компьютерной компании) вы сможете стать настоящим специалистом в IT
(и тут вам внезапно надоест учить все эти языки (впрочем, это уже другие истории для других уровней))

Answer (score 2):

А смысл учиться по книжкам? Это все равно, что учиться водить машину по учебнику. Сразу ставьте перед собой реальную практическую задачу и делайте в начале простой функционал, а позже все более сложный.

Для этой цели хорошо подходит Youtube. Там полно практических уроков, которые имеют цель выполнить реализацию какого-то определенного функционала. Если знаний совсем мало - изучайте все основы по порядку. Когда будете более-менее "плавать", учите именно то, что потребуется в вашей будущей деятельности (все изучить все равно не получится, выбирайте практические темы).

Comment: Перед вождением машины обязательно требуют выучить книжку под названием «Правила дорожного движения»

Comment: А кто-нибудь скажет, что и книжку по основам устройства автомобиля тоже почитать надо

Comment: "А смысл учиться по книжкам?" -- первые года полтора моего знакомства с программированием, архитектурой ОС, железом и основами алгоритмов прошли именно по книжкам, с тетрадкой на 98 листов и карандашом. Ибо компьютер был доступен хорошо если раз в неделю на полчаса. Офигительный и мощнейший опыт, которого сейчас ой как не хватает многим смотрителям видеоуроков...

Comment: @andreymal кто-то должен был это написать:) А так автор прав, сейчас лучшее место для изучения самых основ - youtube, нет особого смысла читать какую либо книгу, если не понятны самые базовые вещи.