# Backend под Linux

Tags: java, c#, linux, backend

Доброе время суток. Решили с другом начать изучать Веб. Он взял на себя frontend, я выбрал backend. В качестве ОС - Ubuntu Server 16.04.3. Вообще мало знакомы с Вебом. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой язык лучше выбрать: Java или C# (на шарпе полтора года практики (WF, Unity3D), с Java недавно начал знакомиться (Minecraft Modding)) и какие особенности (трудности) с написанием под Linux (всю свою жизнь на Окнах сижу). По возможности можете порекомендовать гайды/туториалы/книги. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Да что угодно. Определитесь с языком, откройте метку [tag:книги] и найдите по нему материалы.

Comment: Бекэнд - Java, Node.js, PHP - то, на чем часто делают бекэнд. C# для разработки под Linux я бы выбирать не стал, ибо столкнетесь еще с Mono, что может вытечь в головную боль...

Comment: @D-side кажется лучше давать ссылку на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454684/268670) ответ

Comment: @diraria ок. Давайте :) Я не считаю его достаточно релевантным.

Comment: @selya зачем mono? Про .net core не слышали ? Если знаком с# смело выбирай его. Под Linux все хорошо работает.

Comment: @selya интересно узнать насколько сейчас Core 2.0 поддерживается линуксами, и есть ли хостинг линуксовоый с его поддержкой, я пол года назад по Core 1.0 так и не нашёл хостинга.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин честно говоря, сам я с core не связывался и связываться не хочу. К самому c# у меня меньше неприязни, ибо сам с него начинал, писал на юнити, но c# под линуксом...

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин а что вы подразумеваете под хостингом поддерживающим .Net Core ? На  линуксовый хостинг вполне реально установить сабж. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @Bulson я вопрос перенёс сюда -  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762520/Есть-ли-уже-где-то-рабочий-asp-net-core-2-0-хостинг/762523

Answer (score 1):

На чет писать это уже решать вам решать, если знаком c#. Можно писать веб сервисы на Asp.net core.

Я бы сначала начал изучать веб, чем выбирать, так глобально.

Comment: Я бы еще вот эту [ссылку](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/) дал.