# Есть ли уже где-то рабочий ASP.NET Core хостинг?

Tags: хостинг, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2

Везде пишется что ASP.NET Core это мультиплатформенная технология, которая работает в том числе и на Linux.

Я вот пробовал найти хостинг под 2.0 так и не нашёл. Хочу спросить у участников сообщества, кто-то такой хостинг видел, и если да, то пробовали, и какие результаты? Если даже не хостинг, то пробовали ли у себя на Linux запустить ASP.NET Core приложения? Если да, то какие результаты, насколько стабильно работает платформа? Какие перспективы в этом плане?

Comment: Дмитрий, не хотите немного расширить свой вопрос? 2.0 уже снят вендором с поддержки, возможно просто уберёте конкретную версию из заголовка?

Comment: Hормальный вариант с поддержкой веб-публикаций из визуалстудии есть у https://realhost.pro/hosting/aspnet

Answer (score 1):

Может, я что-то не понимаю, но тебе нужен просто сервер! Работает, хорошо, проблем с запуском под Linux не было. Если хочешь поиграться и попробовать разместить сервис или сайт под mvc, то советую воспользоваться любым облаком. Я использую Azure.

Единственное, что у тебя могут возникнуть проблемы с самим Linux, если до этого не работал.

Тестил еще до официального выхода .net core. Проблем с запуском не было. Да и сейчас нету.

Comment: Если VDS брать то это дороже чем просто shared hosting, да и админить желания нету особого. Хотелось бы обычный shared hosting под linux.

Answer (score 1):

Купите себе VDS/VPS, поставьте себе Ubuntu 16.04 / WinServer и пользуйтесь на здоровье. (в своих проектах для дева использую 1 вариант, для продакшна - второй)

Ссылка почитать: [тыц](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction?tabs=aspnetcore2x).

Из хостингов могу посоветовать *[Smarterasp](https://www.smarterasp.net/hosting_plans)* (тариф за $4.95)

Comment: Правильно ли я вас понимаю что под Ubuntu ASP.NET Core работает хорошо?

Comment: Как раз смотрел недавно Smarterasp, но так и не понял там на линукс или на windows... Что-то у них не ясно написано. Я просто, честно говоря думал что обычные Linux хостеры будут в скором времени ASP поддерживать, но почему-то такого нету, либо я незаметил.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, да, не хуже чем на WinServer

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин насколько я помню, то там Windows. Но если вы не хотите админить сервер, то какая вам разница?)

Comment: у меня вопрос чисто гипотетический )) я хочу понять насколько обширно внедряется ASP.NET на Linux хостинг и какие в этом перспективы. Сейчас мой проект хостится на Windows VDS, но если ASP.NET Core распространяется и на Linux то думаю сменить хостинг... но видимо пока рано об этом говорить, так как я понял из ваших ответов и моего поиска через поисковики, Linux хостинги не спешат его поддерживать.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин просто никто не хочет копаться в Linux, если можно поставить все на Windows и не париться)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, хостингов-то таких много. Можете осваивать Azure от майкрософт или AWS от Amazon и много кто ещё.

Я вот на праздниках потестировал AppHarbor ([тынц раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/790103/213987), [тынц два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/790036/213987)), поддержка framework 2.0 в частности и в целом asp.net core заявлена и работает. Правда, лимиты бесплатного там ну очень маленькие (база SQL - 20 мегабайт), а за плату как-то ну совсем негуманный прайс - поэтому я присматриваюсь к варианту [AspHostPortal, тариф Host on](https://asphostportal.com/ASPNET-Core-2-0-Hosting.aspx)

По самой технологии. Использовать в реальных проектах пока не приходилось, корпоративный сектор - вещь достаточно консервативная, однако технология IMHO уже достаточно созревшая и стабильная, чтобы уже в этом году делать на ней проекты.

Update 2019

Я много лет держу несколько сайтов в мастерхосте, там в основном php-проекты. И держал у них же сервер MS SQL, теперь вот попробовал и netcore погонять (на win-тарифе с IIS8). Впечатления весьма приятные, проблем особых не вылезло на паре демо-приложений (типиповое mvc-приложение от майкрософт, простое winapi приложение) и первом попавшемся рабочем проекте. Так что если нужен хостинг в России с нужными лицензиями на телематику -- можно и такой вариант рассмотреть.

Answer (score 1):

.net core теперь есть у masterhost: Core поддерживается на всех тарифах win-хостинга, доступен .NET Core 2.2.7 и 3.0.0

Comment: 2.2.7 тоже у них есть .

Comment: Топикстартер спрашивал про актуальную на тот момент версию asp.net core (которая год как [снята с поддержки](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) вендором и нормальными хостерами). Наличие 2.х вполне тянет на ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В результате выбрал обычный VPS на Ubuntu. Доволен.
На данный момент Asp.Net Core уже очень стабильно работает под Linux Ubuntu.
Хостю свой сайт уже около года.
Цена VPS на убунту примерно равна цене shared хостинга на Windows, так что вариант VPS мне нравится больше. Администрирование Ubuntu для меня оказалось проще чем администрировать Windows Server, и проблемой не стало, да и опыт полезный.
Список всех хостингов не дам, но одни из топовых это DigitalOcean и Hetzner, я хостюсь на Hetzner и доволен.