# Подключение базы MSSQL к проекту appharbor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Создал новый проект asp.net mvc (.Net Framework, версия 4.6.1), залил на appharbor, работает.

Однако при попытке добавить в проект Entity Framework на моей девелоперской машине работает, а при заливке на appharbor базу не видит.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы подключить базу в приложении? В разделе Addons база добавлена:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Строка подключения:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=srv-sql;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если в приложении уже есть строка подключения - то appharbor после компиляции приложения заменит её.

Однако нужно проделать также следующие манипуляции.

Заходим в пункт меню Add-ons, снова заходим в SQL Server и кликаем по пункту Go to SQL Server:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего прописываем Connectionstring alias на имя той Connection string, которую нам нужно заменить в конфиге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для "винтажных" приложений (не Code First) надо прописывать ещё что-то типа `res://*/DB.csdl|res://*/DB.ssdl|res://*/DB.msl)` в метадату, но не пригодилось.

Документация: https://support.appharbor.com/kb/add-ons/using-sequelizer