# Определение настроек prod/dev по connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Делаю небольшое веб-приложение для работы с лаками для ногтей.

И нужно мне как-то визуально определять, работаю я в данный момент на продакшн версии сайта или на девелоперской, я обычно смотрю на внешний вид логотипа в шапке: на продакшене выглядит так

[image: prod logo]

А dev версия выглядит так:

[image: dev logo]

И сейчас это сделано через анализ адресной строки, в файле Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml:

```
@functions{
    private bool IsDevEnv()
    {
        return Context.Request.Host.Value.Contains("localhost");
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
....
@if (IsDevEnv())
{
    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">Polish <span>Hub</span></a>
}
else
{
    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">Polish Hub</a>
}
```

Однако это не совсем то, что мне нужно: мне нужно проверять параметры sql server connection string, а не hostname сервера. (К сожалению, таковы особености appharbor'а по работе с core на текущий день - в классическом asp.net mvc нормально происходят [замены переменных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/790036/213987))

Как можно добраться до этих настроек (connection string)в asp.net core?

Можно ли как-то в view добраться до Configuration.GetConnectionString? Или, если нельзя, то с какого уровня определить переменную mode (prod/dev), чтобы пробрасывать её в layout страницы.

Comment: Когда я увидел беглым взглядом вашу версию `dev версия`, то я прочитал её как PornHub, боюсь, не у меня одного такие ассоциации возникнут, с этим надо что-то делать :)

Comment: @Bulson Ну что ж, вы молодец - первый разглядели... С ПЕРВЫМ АПРЕЛЯ!!!

Comment: Только что я говорил, что меня никто еще не разыграл сегодня, и на тебе :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

До настроек во View можно добраться через `@inject`

Допустим у нас в `appSettings.json` написано такое

```
{
    "SomeOption" : {
        "SomeProp" : 1000
    }
}
```

Создадим класс `MyAppOptions` и в нем создадим свойство с названием совпадающим с названием опции

```
public int SomeProp { get; set; }
```

Теперь перейдем к `Startup.cs` в нем у нас уже должно быть поле

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
```

которому присваивается значение через конструктор. Далее переходим в метод `ConfigureServices(...)` и добавляем такое

```
services.Configure<MyAppOptions>(_configuration.GetSection("SomeOption"));
```

Теперь во View

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@inject IOptions<MyAppOptions> options

@в нужном месте@
@options.Value.SomeProp
```

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо @Bullson за указание правильного ответа, сделал у себя так:

В startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<MyAppOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SqlConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
});
```

Сам класс настроек:

```
public class MyAppOptions
{
    public SqlConnectionStringBuilder SqlConnectionStringBuilder { get; set; }

    public bool IsDevEnv => this.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity;
}
```

(Я воспользовался тем, что на dev окружение я захожу без пароля по логину windows)

И во Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml я делаю inject настроек:

```
@using AuroraBorealis.PolishHub.WebApp.Data
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@inject IOptions<MyAppOptions> options
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
....
@if (options.Value.IsDevEnv)
{
    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">Polish <span>Hub</span></a>
}
else
{
    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">Polish Hub</a>
}
```

Ссылки по теме:

- [Настройка приложения ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration)
- [Передача конфигурации через IOptions](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/6.3.php)
- [Configuring properties from config.json using services.Configure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27318935/5752652)
- [Конфигурация ASP.NET Core приложения через IOptions](https://blog.zwezdin.com/2016/configuring-aspnet-core-apps-with-ioptions/)

Comment: Ну а вообще условие учитывает дату: первого апреля IsDevEnv инвертируется: http://polishhub.apphb.com/ ;)