# Отношение один к разным типам объектов

Tags: java, c#, sql, entity-framework, архитектура

Я не знаю, есть ли какой-то готовый термин, поэтому в заголовок вынес "один-к-разным-типам-объектов", но это не термин из EF-диаграмм (один-ко-многим, многие-ко-многим и т.п.)

Вот с какой задачей на архитектуру я столкнулся. Меня интересует каким образом можно выразить (в первую очередь на слое реляционном, во вторую - на уровне классов) отношение один-к-разным типам объектов.

Пример из практики, несколько упрощённый. В базе данных существует таблица денежных переводов (`MoneyTransfers`) между пользователями сайта с полями:

- идентификатор перевода `MoneyTransferId`,
- участник-отправитель `SourceUserId`,
- участник-получатель `DestinationUserId`,
- величина перевода `AmountRur`.

В базе есть таблица заказов (`Orders`). Это [сайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/807868/213987) групповых закупок, участники объединяются для того, чтобы сэкономить на доставке товара из-за рубежа.

И вот для учёта кто за что кому когда платил (а бардак там бывает знатный, особенно на какую-нибудь чёрную пятницу) сделана ещё одна таблица, `OrderEntries`:

- идентификатор `OrderEntryId`,
- сумма `AmountRur`,
- идентификатор перевода `MoneyTransferId`,
- идентификатор заказа `OrderId`.

Т.е. фактически это связь многие-ко-многим между Order и MoneyTransfer с промежуточной таблицей. Удобно в практике: можно оплатить заказ несколькими переводами, можно одним переводом оплатить сразу несколько заказов - и по всему этому удобно строить отчёты.

Проблема появляется, когда помимо заказов-закупок девочки захотели продавать друг другу лачки. Вот тут и появилась вторая таблица в дополнение к `Orders` — таблица сделок (`Opportunitites`), а с ней появилась и проблема, вынесенная в заголовок.

Таблиц у меня две, при этом в OrderEntries мне нужно указать к чему относится эта запись - к Order или к Opprtunity.

Как быть?

Можно пойти по пути объединения таблиц Order и Opportunity в одну сущность. При этом допустим такая ORM как Entity Framework [предлагает](https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level2/2_8.php) три варианта для хранения данных: Table Per Hierarchy, Table Per Type и Table Per Concrete Type. Причём все способы имеют значительные недостатки, либо в удобстве работе, либо с производительностью.

Можно пойти по пути создания на таблице OrderEntry двух полей EntityType и EntityId. При этом поле EntityType будет иметь низкую селективность, а проконтролировать ограничение EntityId как внешнего ключа я вообще не представляю себе как.

Другой вариант - сделать на таблице OrderEntry два nullable столбца - один OrderId, другой OpportunityId и заполнять либо тот, либо другой. Ну, неплохой вариант как кажется.

И последнее, что приходит в голову - это сделать две разных таблицы OrderEntiry - одна будет OrderEntryForOrder, другая - OrderEntryForOpportunity. Тоже вариант, который мне нравится, но меньше чем предыдущий: как мне кажется будет сложнее писать запросы к базе.

Кажется, я перебрал все возможные варианты, ничего не упустил? (Если знаете другой - напишите)

Меня интересуют какой-то типовой подход (best practice) к решению подобной задачи, какой вариант более удобен в реальных системах.

Comment: в чем принципиальная разница между Order и Opportunity?

Comment: @Grundy Это совершенно разные сущности с десятками полей и несколькими вспомогательными таблицами. Принципиальная разница - Opportunity это заказ, который делает один участник системы у другого; Order - это групповой заказ, который делают участники системы у какого-то внешнего поставщика. Попытки сводить к единой сущности через "Opportunity - это вырожденный Order с единственным участником" приводят к такому жуткому коду (потому что есть несколько подтипов Order и несколько подтипов Opportunity), что идти по варианту объединения в мегасущность нет никакого желания.

Comment: *два nullable столбца* — потом появится необходимость привязывать третий тип сущностей, будете добавлять третий столбец?

Comment: *Попытки сводить к единой сущности* — как вариант сделать свойство типа `abstract class OrderLinkBase` и в него помещать экземпляры `OrderLink : OrderLinkBase` или `OpportunityLink : OrderLinkBase`, которые будут иметь уже в себе ссылку на сам заказ того или иного типа. Правда я хз как EF это всё переварит, но попробовать можно

Comment: А вообще у нас в КИС используется подход с `EntityId`, но у нас Id во всех таблицах не пересекаются между собой (добавляется префикс с Id таблицы или типа того), правда у нас вообще КИС покупная и она не на .NET-стеке. А насчет того как контролируется целостность — надо уточнить...

Answer (score 1):

> Можно пойти по пути создания на таблице OrderEntry двух полей EntityType и EntityId. При этом поле EntityType будет иметь низкую селективность, а проконтролировать ограничение EntityId как внешнего ключа я вообще не представляю себе как.

Встречал на практике вот этот вариант и он был очень даже работоспособен. Проверка целостности в этом случае, естественно, осуществляется уже не на уровне БД. Индекс должен быть композитный - сразу по двум полям.

> Другой вариант - сделать на таблице OrderEntry два nullable столбца - один OrderId, другой OpportunityId и заполнять либо тот, либо другой. Ну, неплохой вариант как кажется.

Он не масштабируется. В тех системах, с которыми я работал - количество таких таблиц со временем увеличивалось до 20-30.

> И последнее, что приходит в голову - это сделать две разных таблицы OrderEntiry - одна будет OrderEntryForOrder, другая - OrderEntryForOpportunity. Тоже вариант, который мне нравится, но меньше чем предыдущий: как мне кажется будет сложнее писать запросы к базе.

Аналогично.

Comment: Спасибо за мнение. Мы тут [в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48392524#48392524) обсуждали, что две таблицы OrderEntity выглядит неплохим вариантом: уже написанный код не меняется, идёт добавление нового.

Comment: Это про `OrderEntityForOrder` и `OrderEntityForOpportunity`. Я считаю, что это тоже плохо масштабируется. Представьте, что вы у вас таких таблиц стало штук 10 и вы поняли, что во все эти Order* надо добавить одно и то же поле + навернуть логику с ним связанную.