# Как достать ConnectionString из конфигурации в asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Файл конфиг

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=data;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

пытаюсь получить строку подключения в абстрактном классе возможно нужно делать что-то в классе startup но я не совсем понимаю

```
static IConfiguration Configuration;
string con = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings

Comment: ну ок у меня не Ef а ado.net

Comment: Это как то мешает считать строку подключения?

Comment: IConfiguration должен инжектиться через конструктор, либо юзать тот что уже есть в стартапе

Comment: Так. Этот конфиг относится к DAL. Соответственно, из этого слоя вы должны извлекать строку без проблем. Да? А из других слоёв вы должны просто обращаться к DAL! Другие слои не должны знать, откуда DAL берёт строку подключения. Они просто берут _готовые данные_ из DAL. И даже не знают, где они хранятся: может в РСУБД, может в файле, может в NoSQL БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ аналогичен тому что я [определял](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/807847/213987) по Connection string настройки dev/prod.

Допустим у вас есть класс MyAppOption:

```
public class MyAppOptions
{
    public MyAppOptions(SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder)
    {
    }
}
```

В startup.cs пишете в духе:

```
services.Configure<MyAppOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SqlConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
});
```

Ссылки по теме:

- [Настройка приложения ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration)
- [Передача конфигурации через IOptions](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/6.3.php)
- [Configuring properties from config.json using services.Configure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27318935/5752652)
- [Конфигурация ASP.NET Core приложения через IOptions](https://blog.zwezdin.com/2016/configuring-aspnet-core-apps-with-ioptions/)

Comment: Вообще конечно дубликат полный, однако там вопрос в заголовке более узко сформулирован - лучше пусть сюда ведёт из поиска.

Comment: У меня так не получиться мне нужен connection string на data acces layer

Comment: @Kioshilol Класс типа MyAppOptions может лежать в любом проекте и всё равно DI его инициализирует, что такого особенного в проекте DAL, что вдруг "не сработает"? Ничего. Вы описываете какую-то странную ситуацию, у меня ближайшая аналогия - "пытаюсь нажать клавишу "л", но печатается "ё"". Вам надо научиться поработать с DI, поинициализировать разные строковые/интовые переменные в разных проектах и понять, что под капотом нет никакой особой магии (как вам кажется сейчас).