# Как включить поддержку asp.net mvc core на appharbor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Создал в студии пустой проект asp.net mvc core (target framework = 2.0), на моей локальной машине запускается и работает.

Однако когда я делаю git push на appharbor, то проект вроде как компилируется, но не деплоится:

[image: core on appharbor]

Можно как-то задеплоить asp.net mvc core на appharbor или пока этот хостинг вообще не поддерживает core? Или поддерживает, но не 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Поддержка оказывается есть и проекты нормально собираются на framework 2.0

Что для этого нужно поменять в решении.

Нужно открыть в каком-либо редакторе типа блокнот файл WebApplication1.csproj и сделать две вещи.

Во-первых, нужно добавить Publish как цель по умолчанию.

Первая строка имеет вид:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Нужно её заменить на:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" DefaultTargets="Publish">
```

Во-вторых, нужно указать путь, куда публиковать файлы.

Ищем строки:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Изменим на:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishDir>$(OutDir)_PublishedWebsites\NetCoreWebApp\</PublishDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Всё, после коммита и пуша:

[image: published]

Comment: Давно этим хостингом пользуйтесь? Какие впечатления?