# xamarin где разворачивать backеnd мобильного приложения

Tags: c#, сервер, xamarin, backend

Коллеги, решил разработать приложение, и задался вопросом, какой бэкэнд лучше использовать для мобильного приложения, и почему.
Пока слышал только про firebase но мб еще какие советы дадите.
Буду благодарен

Comment: Вы говорите "бэкенд", но подхоже понимаете под этим "база данных". Вопрос вкуса, но я для C# предпочитаю родной для стека MS SQL. Я вот только не особо люблю mysql/mariadb - и не потому что не умею готовить, напротив я очень их люблю, но в LAMP стеке, но накушался уже разного рода проблем с драйверами (и открытыми и проприетарными), просто не хочу этого "счастья". Если не хотите MS SQL - то посмотрите в сторону posrtgre, многие кто уходит с mysql на неё переходят. Оракл - это больше для крупного ентерпрайза, вряд ли вам стоит туда

Comment: @AK Спасибо за ответ, а какие сервисы лучше использовать? Т.е. где разворачивать, облако от микрософт azure подойдет, или это не то?

Comment: Облако от azure - это самое родное для платформы облако, с ним интеграция будет самая простая и идёт из коробки. Если интересует что-то иное - то посмотрите в этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/762520/213987) люди советовали хостинги, есть и моя рекомендация.

Comment: @AK Благодарю, буду изучать azure =)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ дан @AK:

> Облако от azure - это самое родное для платформы облако, с ним
>   интеграция будет самая простая и идёт из коробки. Если интересует
>   что-то иное - то посмотрите в [этом
>   вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/762520/213987) люди советовали
>   хостинги, есть и моя рекомендация.