# Настройки для выгрузки ASP.NET Core проекта на мастерхост

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[Пробовал как-то net core хостинг от мастерхост](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/762520/213987), заливал тестовый проект -- работало.

Сейчас решил ещё один сайт создать, а настройки публикации не сохранил. На сайте провайдера тоже нет.

Какие должны быть настройки публикации?

Answer (score 1):

Работают такие настройки:

> Deployment-mode: Framework-Dependent
>
> Target-runtime: win-x86 (генерит меньше файлов для деплоя) или Portable

[image: настройки публикации проекта]

А вот win-x64 не работает :(

Ссылка на режимы деплоя на скрине [ведёт сюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index).