# Подходят ли книги описывающие Питон 3.4 для изучения Питона (последняя версия 3.6)

Tags: python, книги

Добрый день. Сразу скажу, что я новичок в программировании. Первым языком решил выбрать Python, так как хочу заниматься машинным обучением. Но возникла проблема с выбором литературы. Сомневаюсь в корректности выбора обучающей литературы.  Как уже понял, последняя версия Python - 3.6. Но учебники, которые я нашел, охватывают лишь 3.4. Стоил ли остановиться на этих ресурсах или же искать более современные учебники? Есть опасения, что в учебниках может быть представлена устаревшая информация и потом придется переучивать. Возможно я рассуждаю неправильно, не судите строго, я только делаю первые шаги в программировании. Прошу помощи в неравнодушных людей. Порекомендуйте действительно стоящие ресурсы, которые помогут в изучении. Актуальна ли информация в учебниках, которые были написаны пару лет назад? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Смотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/454684#454684)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. "Стоил ли остановиться на этих ресурсах или же искать более современные учебники?" -- пока будете искать новые учебники  по версии 3.6 - выйдет версия 3.8. И дальше что? Вердикт - читайте любые книги по Python 3...  Если и будут изменения - потом будете разбираться именно в изменениях. Это всегда проще, чем учить "от печки".
2. "в учебниках может быть представлена устаревшая информация и потом придется переучивать." -  так и есть. Если хотите заниматься программированием - будьте готовы к тому, что переучиваться придется постоянно, на протяжении всей (профессиональной) жизни. Особенности профессии, так сказать.
3. "Актуальна ли информация в учебниках, которые были написаны пару лет назад?" - вполне актуальна с учетом сказанного в предыдущих двух пунктах.
4. Учтите, что Python - это еще не машинное обучение. Это просто один из инструментов ДЛЯ машинного обучения. Поэтому да, Python -  учить надо, но не менее важно начать учить то, что  составляет базу машинного обучения (матанализ, линейная алгебра, теорвер,..... и в том числе -программирование), а затем и собственно методы машинного обучения.