# С чего начать изучение пентестинга?

Tags: безопасность, книги

Всем привет. Подскажите, с чего нужно начинать изучать пентестинг, какую базу нужно иметь, посоветуйте какую-то литературу по этой теме для чайников, поделитесь опытом или же дайте совет) Спасибо за любую информацию.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: Посмотрите этот курс, очень доходчиво, реальными тестами https://stepik.org/course/127

Comment: https://www.pentestit.ru/courses/

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/282700/

Comment: https://leanpub.com/white-hat-hacking-ru/

Answer (score 3):

*"Хакинг искусство эксплойта"* Д. Эриксон - возможно для старта будет трудновато, книга не столько о пинтесте, а о не стандартном мышлении которым необходимо обладать хакеру, ламеру, или пинтестеру.