# Помогите определиться

Tags: c++, книги

Что лучше почитать по C++ ?
 1. Стефан Рэнди Дэвис - C++ для чайников 
 2. Стивен Прата "Язык программирования С++"

Comment: А в чем тогда вопрос?)

Comment: @selya, Что лучше почитать по C++ ?

Comment: Вы не пробовали искать? Помимо C++, на этом сайте есть [сборники литературы по очень многим темам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454684/198251).

Comment: @AivanF. Я знаю про этот сборник на StackOverflow —
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683. Я сначала туда захожу, а потом спрашиваю что мне непонятно.