# Помощь в выборе литературы

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Нужна помощь в выборе книги, по которой можно (если это возможно) изучить front-end часть веб-программирования. В идеале в объеме, позволяющем претендовать на позицию джуна или уверенные знания для прохождения стажировки

Comment: Изучали раздел [книги и учебные материалы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/Книги-и-другие-материалы-для-обучения)?

Comment: К сожалению когда книги о frontend выходя из типографии являются уже не актуальными. Лучше где-то скачать программу обучения и гуглить статьи на эту тему. Программу например можно взять здесь: https://htmlacademy.ru/intensive/htmlcss#program.

Comment: Понимаю, что актуальными из типографии книги не выходят, но с бумажными материалами лично мне удобнее. Необходим совет для заказа литературы с сервиса ozon к примеру.

Answer (score 1):

**Каналы:**
 Sorax, WebDesign Master, Gloacademy.
**Книги:**
Хуан Диего Гоше - HTML5 Для профессионалов
Б.Фрэйн - HTML5 и CSS3. Разработка сайтов для любых браузеров и устройств
Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL, javascript, CSS и HTML5

Редмонд Э., Уилсон Д. - Семь баз данных за семь недель
Ицик Бен-Ган - Основы T-SQL
Ицик Бен-Ган - Microsoft SQL Server 2012. Создание запросов. Учебный курс Microsoft

Крокфорд - JavaScript. Сильные стороны
Дэвид Флэнаган -  JavaScript. Подробное руководство
Берб Бибо, Иегуда Кац - jQuery. Подробное руководство по продвинутому JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

По HTML и CSS могу посоветовать только видео и каналы. Каналы: Sorax, WebDesign Master, Хауди Хо с его часовыми роликами по основам, loftblog, webtheory.

Дальше нужен JavaScript. Очень хороший курс есть у Sorax'а. У Хауди Хо тоже есть часовой ролик по основам. (Потом можно почитать об JQuery)

После этого учи PHP и MySQL как основы. Опять же Хауди делал хороший видеокурс, также можно посмотреть Гошу Дударя.

После этого всего сам поймёшь, что дальше учить