# ListView не могу правильно поставить условие

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, list, if

Не могу правильно поставить условие

```
for (int i = 0; i < file1.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < file2.Count; j++)
                {
                    // Удаленные строки показываются красным цветом, добавленные - желтым, неизмененные - зеленым.
                    if (file1[i] == file2[j])// НЕ измененая строка - зеленая
                    {
                        ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem();
                        li.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        li.Text = file1[i];
                        listView1.Items.Add(li);
                        break;
                    }
                    if (file1[i] != file2[j]) // Удаленные строки показываются красным цветом,
                    {
                        ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem();
                        li.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        li.Text = file1[i];
                        listView1.Items.Add(li);
                        break;
                    }
                    //else if ...// добавленные - желтым,
                }
            }
```

Удаленные строки показываются красным цветом, добавленные - желтым, неизмененные - зеленым.
У меня 2 списка

```
List<string> file1 = new List<string>();
List<string> file2 = new List<string>();
```

Я ставлю условие что в file найдена строка как и file2 то зеленым, если нет такой то красным ВОТ только цвет изменяется на первой строчке далее идет все красное, а про измененные даже не знаю

Весь код программы:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AnalyzerTwoTextFiles
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        List<string> file1 = new List<string>();
        List<string> file2 = new List<string>();
        private void btn_generation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetFile1();
            WriteToFile();
            GetFile2();
            listView1.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < file1.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < file2.Count; j++)
                {
                    // Удаленные строки показываются красным цветом, добавленные - желтым, неизмененные - зеленым.
                    if (file1[i] == file2[j])// НЕ измененая строка - зеленая
                    {
                        ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem();
                        li.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        li.Text = file1[i];
                        listView1.Items.Add(li);
                        break;
                    }
                    if (file1[i] != file2[j]) // Удаленные строки показываются красным цветом,
                    {
                        ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem();
                        li.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        li.Text = file1[i];
                        listView1.Items.Add(li);
                        break;
                    }
                    //else if ...// добавленные - желтым,
                }
            }
        }

        private List<string> GetFile1()
        {
            file1.Clear();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("File1.txt"))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string[] s = sr.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    string arStr;
                    arStr = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i<s.Length;i++)
                    {
                        arStr += s[i] + " ";
                    }
                    file1.Add(arStr);
                }
                return file1;
            }
        }
        private void WriteToFile()
        {
            using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream("file2.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fstream))
                {
                    string strfile2 = textBox1.Text;
                    fstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                    sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
                }
            }
        }
        private List<string> GetFile2()
        {
            file2.Clear();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("File2.txt"))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string[] s = sr.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    string arStr;
                    arStr = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                    {
                        arStr += s[i] + " ";
                    }
                    file2.Add(arStr);
                }
                return file2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример как должен выглядеть результат рабочий программы

[image: Пример output'a]

Ссылка на проект - https://github.com/wargerun/AnalyzerTwoTextFiles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый файл (образец)

```
Первая строка.
Вторая строка.
Третья строка.
```

Второй файл

```
Первая строка.
3-я строка.
Еще одна строка.
```

Получилось так

[image: пример работы]

Код такой

```
/// <summary>
/// Строка
/// </summary>
class Line
{
    public enum LineType
    {
        Unchanged, //неизмененная
        Added, //добавленная
        Deleted, //удаленная
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public LineType Type { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Text} : {Type}";
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Подсобный класс для сверки строк
/// </summary>
class LineComparer : IEqualityComparer<Line>
{
    public bool Equals(Line x, Line y)
    {
        return x.Text.Equals(y.Text);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Line obj)
    {
        return obj.Text.GetHashCode();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConsoleAppLinesComparison");
        Console.WriteLine();

        var originFile = @"D:\fileOrigin.txt";
        var otherFile = @"D:\fileOther.txt";

        List<Line> originLines = GetLines(originFile);
        List<Line> otherLines = GetLines(otherFile);

        List<Line> resultLines = CheckLines(originLines, otherLines);

        PrintLines(resultLines);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Чтение файла в коллекцию строк
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">путь к файлу</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static List<Line> GetLines(string file)
    {
        List<Line> result = new List<Line>();

        try
        {
            foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(file))
            {
                result.Add(new Line { Text = line });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Чтение {file} c ошибкой: {ex.Message}");
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Сверка двух коллекций строк,
    /// простановка соответ. типов строкам.
    /// Возвращает объединенную коллекцию строк
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="originLines">коллекция образец</param>
    /// <param name="otherLines">коллекция для сверки</param>
    /// <returns>объединенная коллекция строк без повторений</returns>
    private static List<Line> CheckLines(List<Line> originLines, List<Line> otherLines)
    {
        //все строки которых нет в другом файле
        var exceptOriginLines = originLines.Except(otherLines, new LineComparer());
        foreach (var line in exceptOriginLines)
        {
            line.Type = Line.LineType.Deleted;
        }

        //все строки которых нет в оригинальном файле
        var exceptOtherLines = otherLines.Except(originLines, new LineComparer());
        foreach (var line in exceptOtherLines)
        {
            line.Type = Line.LineType.Added;
        }

        //объединенная последовательность (без повторений)
        var unionLines = originLines.Union(otherLines, new LineComparer());

        return unionLines.ToList();
    }

    private static void PrintLines(List<Line> resultLines)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("Неизменные строки");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("Удаленные строки");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("Добавленные строки");

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine(new string('=', 20));
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var line in resultLines)
        {
            if (line.Type == Line.LineType.Unchanged)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine(line.Text);
            }
            else if (line.Type == Line.LineType.Added)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine(line.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(line.Text);
            }

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто забавный факт. Смотрел реализацию `Except` (были сомнения по поводу скорости работы) - оказывается, оно использует внутри [самописную хеш таблицу](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2380) сваянную на линейном пробировании с возможностьюб только добавить или проверить присутствие элемента (или удалить). Прикольно. Получается `Except` работает за линейное время, что хорошо :)

Comment: @tym32167 Снимаю шляпу. Я о таких тонкостях даже и не задумываюсь, если честно.

Comment: @Bulson Спасибо за помощь, выбрал Ваш вариант так как он был проще в понимании для меня), но хотел спросить зачем это свойство - `public override string ToString()` ? И почему вы решили решить задачу именно через интерфейс `IEqualityComparer<T>` ?

Comment: `public override string ToString() ` - это переопределенние метода `ToString()` у `object`, а как известно все классы унаследованы от object`. Конкретно для класса `Line` я это сделал для удобства отладки, когда во время отладки смотришь значения переменных, удобно видеть сразу значения свойств того или иного объекта принадл. классу `Line`. Что касается `IEqualityComparer<T>`, то для правильного сравнения между собой разных экз-ов `Line` потребен вспомогат. класс для правильной работы `Except()` и `Union()`

Answer (score 0):

Определим результат операции

```
public class CompareStringResult
{
    public enum ActionType { Deleted, Added, NotChanged };

    public ActionType Action { get; }
    public string Data { get; }

    public CompareStringResult(string data, ActionType action)
    {
        Data = data;
        Action = action;
    }
}
```

Код для сравнения прост, работает линейное время

```
public IEnumerable<CompareStringResult> Compare(string[] oldValues, string[] newValues)
{
    var result = new List<CompareStringResult>();
    var allLines = new HashSet<string>(oldValues.Union(newValues));
    var oldSet = new HashSet<string>(oldValues);
    var newSet = new HashSet<string>(newValues);

    foreach (var line in allLines)
    {
        var action = CompareStringResult.ActionType.NotChanged;
        if (oldSet.Contains(line) && !newSet.Contains(line)) action = CompareStringResult.ActionType.Deleted;
        if (!oldSet.Contains(line) && newSet.Contains(line)) action = CompareStringResult.ActionType.Added;
        result.Add(new CompareStringResult(line, action));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Как проверить

```
var oldV = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray();
var newV = Enumerable.Range(5, 10).Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray();

foreach(var r in Compare(oldV, newV))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{r.Action} - {r.Data}");
}
```

Вывод

```
Deleted - 0
Deleted - 1
Deleted - 2
Deleted - 3
Deleted - 4
NotChanged - 5
NotChanged - 6
NotChanged - 7
NotChanged - 8
NotChanged - 9
Added - 10
Added - 11
Added - 12
Added - 13
Added - 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю ещё один ответ.

У двух существующих ответов есть плюсы - маленький расход памяти, линейная сложность, но при этом и есть минус - они никак не работают с изначальным порядком строк в исходнике и приёмнике.

Чтобы учитывать этот порядок, можно воспользоваться разными алгоритмами. Я попробую воспользоваться самым простым, что знаю - [Расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0), который мы немного подредактируем под нашу задачу. Сам алгоритм расписан на википедии, повторять его здесь смысла нет.

Итак, что мы в алгоритм изменим:

1) Начнем с того, что расстояние Левенштейна изначально предназначено для символов в тексте. Но мы будем вместо символа в тексте сравнивать строку в наборе строк.

2) Замена одной строки на другую в оригинале считается одной операцией. Но мы будем считать, что это 2 операции (удалить старую строку, добавить новую).

Результат операции будем хранить в следующем классе:

```
public class CompareStringResult
{
    public enum ActionType { Deleted, Added, Changed, NotChanged };

    public ActionType Action { get; }
    public string OldValue { get; }
    public string NewValue { get; }

    public CompareStringResult(string oldValue, string newValue, ActionType action)
    {
        OldValue = oldValue;
        NewValue = newValue;
        Action = action;
    }
}
```

Вот и, по сути, все. Приступим!

```
public IEnumerable<CompareStringResult> Compare(string[] oldValues, string[] newValues)
{

    var board = new int[oldValues.Length + 1, newValues.Length + 1];
    for (var i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++) board[i, 0] = i;
    for (var i = 0; i < board.GetLength(1); i++) board[0, i] = i;

// подготовка таблицы изменений

    for (var i = 1; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (var j = 1; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            var stringsEquals = string.CompareOrdinal(oldValues[i - 1], newValues[j - 1]) == 0;
            var add = (stringsEquals ? 0 : 1);
            board[i, j] = Math.Min(board[i - 1, j - 1] + add * 2, Math.Min(board[i - 1, j] + 1, board[i, j - 1] + 1));
        }
    }


// Идея такая: раз нижний правый угол - наша конечная цель, то, чтобы найти кратчайший путь изменений, нам     придется пройти от конца в начало. Стартуем в нижнем правом углу, заканчиваем в верхнем левом. Но, так как  мы движемся в обратном направлении, то я использовал стек для реверса результата к прямому порядку в конце   функции. 

    var stack = new Stack<CompareStringResult>();

    var ii = board.GetLength(0) - 1;
    var jj = board.GetLength(1) - 1;

    // прогулка из правого нижнего угла таблицы в верхний левый по пути с минимальной суммой
    while (ii > 0 && jj > 0)
    {
        var max = board[ii, jj];

// Очевидно, двигаться мы можем вверх, влево или вверх-влево. Смотрим где наименьший элемент, туда и идем.

        var min = Math.Min(board[ii - 1, jj - 1], Math.Min(board[ii - 1, jj], board[ii, jj - 1]));
        if (min == board[ii - 1, jj - 1])
        {
            if (min != max)
            {
                stack.Push(new CompareStringResult(oldValues[ii - 1], newValues[jj - 1], CompareStringResult.ActionType.Changed));
            }
            else
                stack.Push(new CompareStringResult(newValues[jj - 1], newValues[jj - 1], CompareStringResult.ActionType.NotChanged));

            ii--;
            jj--;
        }
        else if (min == board[ii - 1, jj])
        {
            if (min != max)
                stack.Push(new CompareStringResult(oldValues[ii - 1], null, CompareStringResult.ActionType.Deleted));
            else
                stack.Push(new CompareStringResult(oldValues[ii - 1], newValues[jj], CompareStringResult.ActionType.NotChanged));
            ii--;
        }
        else if (min == board[ii, jj - 1])
        {
            if (min != max)
                stack.Push(new CompareStringResult(null, newValues[jj - 1], CompareStringResult.ActionType.Added));
            else
                stack.Push(new CompareStringResult(oldValues[ii], newValues[jj - 1], CompareStringResult.ActionType.NotChanged));
            jj--;
        }
    }

// Если уперлись в левую стенку, но ещё не дошли до верха

    while (ii > 0)
    {
        var max = board[ii, jj];
        var min = board[ii - 1, jj];

        if (min != max)
            stack.Push(new CompareStringResult(oldValues[ii - 1], null, CompareStringResult.ActionType.Deleted));
        else
            stack.Push(new CompareStringResult(oldValues[ii - 1], newValues[jj], CompareStringResult.ActionType.NotChanged));
        ii--;

    }

// Если уперлись в потолок, но ещё не в левом углу       

    while (jj > 0)
    {
        var max = board[ii, jj];
        var min = board[ii, jj - 1];

        if (min != max)
            stack.Push(new CompareStringResult(null, newValues[jj - 1], CompareStringResult.ActionType.Added));
        else
            stack.Push(new CompareStringResult(oldValues[ii], newValues[jj - 1], CompareStringResult.ActionType.NotChanged));
        jj--;

    }

    return stack;
}
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]

- Черный - нет изменений
- Синий - изменено
- Красный - удалено
- Зеленый - добавлено

Хочу обратить внимание, что сложность алгоритма, как и затраты на память, стали гораздо больше чем в других ответах (N*M), но и качество полученного расстояния выше.

Полный текст примера доступен [тут](https://github.com/tym32167/CompareFiles)

Comment: Спасибо за внимание, но я не понял как мне этот пример поможет((. У меня уже есть [из чего и на что исправить](https://ibb.co/fixpFp) , но я не могу поставить условие при котором будет происходить то или иной действие(удаление, изменение, добавление).

Comment: @Tim так я же написал пример, где на входе 2 набора строк, а на выходе строки с информацией о том, была ли строка удалена\добавлена\изменена. Вы же это и спрашивали? Или я не понял вопроса

Comment: @Tim отправляете свои `file1` и `file2` в мою функцию и получаете на выходе одну последовательность строк с указанием операции над строкой.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, но вы столько всего использовали с чем мне еще предстоит разобраться и было очень сложно анализировать ваш код, а именно: Почему вы решили все реализовать алгоритмом "Расстояние Левенштейна", что за объект `stack` и его метод `push`? @tym32167

Comment: @Tim "Расстояние Левенштейна" показывает нам минимальное количество изменений, которое нужно проделать, чтобы файл А стал файлом Б. По идее, вы его даже можете на измененных строках запускать, чтобы показать не только какие строки изменились, что и что именно в строке было изменено.

Comment: @Tim [Стек](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA) это базовая структура данных, она принимает элементы в одном порядке, возвращает их в реверсном порядке. Она мне понадобилась, так как путь редактирования я строил с конца, с последнего шага к первому, ну а выводить его я хотел от первого к последнему - потому мне надо было порядок шагов реверснуть, чем стек и занимается.

Comment: Вы же мне уже не первый раз помогаете и не только мне, что же вас мотивирует помогать другим?) @tym32167

Comment: @Tim пока помогаешь другим - учишься и сам. Такой своеобразный способ держать  голову в тонусе. А иногда и от вопроса отделаться не можешь. Этот код, например, я заканчивал писать уже в пятом часу утра - не мог уснуть не решив задачку

Comment: Мне никто никогда ничего не объяснял и всегда учился сам не могли вы бы посоветовать как приобретать новые знания. Начал читать книгу Алгоритмы. Руководство по разработке Скиена С.

Comment: @Tim тут на сайте есть подборки книг по C#. Если вам важны именно алгоритмы - то да, Скиена и [Седжвик](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/) для начала. Но книги без практики ничего не дадут - есть много сайтов для тренировки алгоритмов, например codeforces. Но вообще вам желательно самому понять, для чего и чему вы хотите научиться, а когда поймете, тогда поиск материалов не будет проблемой.

Comment: Вы сказали есть много сайтов для тренировки, не могли бы Вы посоветовать еще несколько, что то типа GeekBrains.

Comment: @Tim `GeekBrains` - это курсы, про них ничего не могу сказать. Я сам проходил только бесплатные курсы на coursera, на степике (stepik.org). Сайты для тренировок алгоритмов - codeforces, hackerrank, topcoder, leetcode. Если вы хотите научиться писать что то конкретное (веб сайты. например), то садитесь и пишите + учитесь что и как делать уже в процессе.

Comment: @Tim а вообще заходите в [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--), там периодически находятся опытные коллеги (иногда и я заглядываю), они могут помочь советом с подобными вопросами - с чего начать. что читать и тд

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать!

Comment: @Tim отмечайте галкой те ответы, что вам действительно помогли решить изначальную проблему. Не надо отмечать мой ответ просто потому что я вам помог с литературой :)

Comment: @Tim [Книги и другие материалы для обучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)