# Как называется методика (алгоритм) сравнения текста двух документов в Microsoft Office Word?

Tags: java, алгоритм, текст, сравнение, анализ-данных

В программе Word (Office) есть функция "Сравнить", по вызову которого сравнивается текст двух файлов. Методов (алгоритмы) сравнений много "шингла", "бленда" и т.д, но не могу понять как называется метод который используется в офисе.

Как называется алгоритм (методика) сравнения (схожести) текста реализованная в программе Word? Хотелось бы узнать именно название этого алгоритма (методики), а дальше уже погуглю.

Скриншот для понимания:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мне кажется, вы не узнаете название этого алгоритма, только разве что если он в документации где то написан. А вообще алгориимов сравнения текстов есть много же, тот же простейший левенштейн или какой нить k-diff

Comment: @tym32167 а алгоритм который использует word на какой из алгоритмов больше похож?

Comment: я когда то [писал алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/868766/179763) на основе расстояния левенштейна, но я сомневаюсь, что он тут используется, это было бы слишком просто.