# Выделить различия между словами в строках

Tags: алгоритм, compare

Подскажите пожалуйста как написать алгоритм.

На вход поступает две строки, например:

Первая: самолёт

Вторая: самокат

В итоге нужно записать слово в файл с выделенными различиями, например:

<лёт>  само"кат"

в скобки <> вставить символы что удалились
в кавычки "" вставить символы что добавились или заменились в слове

Еще один пример:

Первая последовательность: When I hear

Вторая последовательность: The thing always appears

в итоге должно быть:

<.w> "t" he <.n> "thing"<.I> "always" <.h> "app"ear"s"

Сравнивать только похожие слова если слова совсем не похожи то считать что они заменены другим или просто добавлены,
как в случае с hear и always, hear не сравнивается с always так как они не похожи, но hear сравнивается с appears так как последовательности ear совпадают.

Comment: Может кто-то и напишет готовый код, но пока посоветую посмотреть [Расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Расстояние_Левенштейна). А также в книге "Алгоритмы. Вводный курс" Томаса Кормена главу "Алгоритмы на строках" - там как раз то, что вам нужно: "Наидлиннейшая общая подпоследовательность" и "Преобразование одной строки в другую".

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Вам надо что то [типа такого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/868766/179763), только примененная не на список строк, а на список символов (чем строка и является)

Comment: ООО, спасибо большое, то что нужно))